# Open irc:// links in XChat from Firefox and Chromium

Tags: firefox, chromium, xchat

I want to open channels in servers specified in `irc://` links in XChat, but directly pointing to XChat binary (in Firefox) did not work - the window to choose servers appears as usual. I don't know how to associate `irc://` links with XChat in Chromium.

Comment: there is a link here that describes various workarounds for older versions of firefox and xchat - maybe it still works? http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-25372.html

Comment: Hmm, if `xchat --existing --url=$@` could be converted to a Terminal command... I don't want to create a script. Too much of a chore to do it every time I format the PC.

Comment: possibly something like `bash -c "xchat --existing --url=$@"` ?

Comment: Well, the Bash script worked, couldn't use the Terminal command. So if you can post it as an answer, I can be done with this question.

Comment: Note that most [HexChat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HexChat) (XChat fork) users don’t need this, because HexChat [fixed the issue in 2013](https://github.com/hexchat/hexchat/commit/aab55d8cffc577a7aec4f43d5157c7e3f498c0f5).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution is to make a little script to open the irc chanel in an existing xchat, and pass that to Firefox.

For example - make a file in `/usr/bin` called `xchat-firefox` and put in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
xchat --existing --url=$@
```

Add executable permission to the script:

```
sudo chmod +x xchat-firefox
```

Now using the menu option `Edit-Preferences-Applications Tab` in Firefox select "xchat-firefox" for the "irc" content-type.

[source 1](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-125584.html) & [source 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-25372.html)

Answer (score 7):

Fossfreedom's method works great, but it is a per-app solution. Granted, firefox/chromium is *the* most common use case, but it is easy to make a system-wide solution so it would automatically works for *all* apps automatically, with no need to configure each one.

The solution is to create an alternative `.desktop` file associating xchat with the `irc://` uri scheme. This will automatically make the whole desktop (and any app) see XChat as an IRC handler.

Copy xchat launcher so we can edit it:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/xchat.desktop ./xchat-irc-handler.desktop
```

Edit its contents, adding `MimeType` and `NoDisplay`, and replacing `Exec` to match this:

```
Exec=xchat --existing --url=%u
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/irc;
NoDisplay=true
```

Now install the file. This can be done for your current user only or for all users (just prepend the command with `sudo`):

```
xdg-desktop-menu install --novendor ./xchat-irc-handler.desktop
```

And that's it! You can try results immediately, in Firefox, Chromium, or *any* application. Let's test it in terminal:

```
xdg-open 'irc://chat.freenode.org/#ubuntu'
```

***Ta-da!***