# Apply icons to bash scripts

Tags: scripts, icons

I created a script for XChat [according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55779/open-irc-links-in-xchat-from-firefox-and-chromium/60325#60325), and I was wondering if there is anyway to apply XChat icon to it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Create a .desktop file like this and put it in /usr/share/applications/

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=XChat Firefox
Exec=/usr/bin/your_script
Icon=/usr/share/icons/xchats_icon
```

"XChat Firefox" will then be a launchable application with XChat's icon. `Exec` can also take a bash command (with arguments, optionally) as its value.

For a complete explanation of the .desktop format, see [this specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html#introduction).

Answer (score 2):

After copying your appname.desktop file to /usr/share/applications you may have to wait a few minutes while kbuildsycoca4 rebuilds the system config cache.