# Tiny monitor icons in GNOME Display Arrangement with multiple monitors

Tags: nvidia, gnome, multiple-monitors, display, icons

I use 7 monitors: in a 3 over + 3 under +1 portrait configuration. GNOME Display Arrangement draws 7 very tiny monitor icons with a huge amount of white space. The icons are so small that I cannot reliably rearrange them. I can hardly even select them or move them around. Is there a fix for this issue?

Aside from that, video displays very nicely on all monitors and there are no other issues. I'm using onboard Intel video and PCIe Nvidia GTX 760. I have included a Display Arrangement screenshot, and also magnified the tiny icons for comparison. Its quite chaotic. There is also a pic of the actual monitors, and finally the Nvidia X Server Settings.

I have reviewed the GNOME monitors.xml file and found 2 duplicate entries and deleted them. It did not resolve the issue. Even if I disable all of the monitors then re-enable them one by one, by the time the 5th and 6th monitors are enabled the icons are almost too small to rearrange.

[image: Display Arrangement very small]

[image: actual monitors]

[image: NVIDIA X Server Settings]

UPDATE:

No fix identified for this graphical issue yet (10 days), so in the meantime I have manually edited the monitors.xml file.  I use four different screen configurations (bottom middle screen only, 3 bottom, 3 bottom+TV, all monitors). Since I can't rely on moving the tiny monitor icons around in GNOME Display Arrangement I have made 4 different monitors.xml to match the 4 required configurations. Then I made 4 bash scripts and associated 4 application launcher icons to them. Now I can rapidly switch between all screens, 4 screens, 1 screen, etc. This is much faster than manually disabling/enabling/moving screens around. The only downside is that often the screen switching is destructive and all applications are closed and I have to log back in (even though I'm using SIGQUIT). But at least I can now easily change the screen configuration.

Thanks to the users for these helpful posts:

[How to associate an icon with a shell script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99635/how-to-associate-an-icon-with-a-shell-script)

[Apply icons to bash scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60667/apply-icons-to-bash-scripts)

[How to restart Gnome-shell, after it became unresponsive/freeze?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455301/how-to-restart-gnome-shell-after-it-became-unresponsive-freeze/496999)

Answer (score 1):

No fix found for Ubuntu 18.04. Anyhow, I upgraded to 20.04 and the problem is resolved.  Problem does not exist in 20.04... working perfectly now. Many thanks to the developers!