# How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, xkb, xbindkeys

I want to change the key bindings on some of the keys on my keyboard.  I want some to run commands and others to activate different keys.

What applications can I use to do this?

---

**Index:**

- [Xbindkeys](https://askubuntu.com/a/254425/44179)
- [Default keyboard and shortcut settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/254442/44179) (from within System Settings)
- [Xmodmap](https://askubuntu.com/a/257497/44179)
- [Xkeycaps](https://askubuntu.com/a/300203/44179)
- [Autokey](https://askubuntu.com/a/304834/44179)
- [xkb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/706210#706210)

---

### I'm still looking for answers using dconf and any other method.

Comment: Does maybe xmacro belong in this answer? it can "Record / Play keystrokes and mouse movements in X displays".

Comment: @roadmr If I can use it to create custom keyboard shortcuts, then yes!

Comment: Thanks for adding this thread.  I'm looking for a way to use a key just like a mouse button (hold and drag, click, etc).  This seems to be missing from the thread.

Comment: @krumpelstiltskin Currently I am unaware of any way to achieve such exact duplication of a mouse. I suggest you ask a new question. If I do figure it out I can still answer there, or someone else might have a better answer :)

Comment: here is a `xkb`-answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/347382/354350

Comment: One more solution: ACTKBD. Recognizes also different keyboards. so you can work with 2 keyboards and map one of them. http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~thkala/projects/actkbd/

Answer (score 112):

## xbindkeys..

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

Xbindkeys is a very versatile program that lets you remap keys very easily.  It uses a config file, my default located in your home directory, to change key bindings into certain commands.

To create a default config file you use the command:

```
xbindkeys --defaults
```

Which prints the default config file.  So if you want to *create* the file containing the default values you would use:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
```

Which prints the default values into a hidden file named `.xbindkeysrc` located in home (`~`).

Now to actually *change* the bindings of keys we first need to know what the name or keysym of those keys is.  `xbindkeys` allows us to use the `-k` handle to find the name of a key or key combination.  Run:

```
xbindkeys -k
```

And press a key or key combination.  Your output will look *something* similar to this (when pressing <kbd>space</kbd>):

```
"NoCommand"
m:0x10 + c:65
Mod2 + space
```

`"No Command"` tells us that currently no command is associated with the <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

```
m:0x10 + c:65
Mod2 + space
```

Is the name of the key/key combination.

## the config file..

Lets open up the config file you made earlier:

```
gedit .xbindkeysrc
```

Here is an excerpt from the default config file:

```
#
# A list of keys is in /usr/include/X11/keysym.h and in
# /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h
# The XK_ is not needed.
#
# List of modifier:
#   Release, Control, Shift, Mod1 (Alt), Mod2 (NumLock),
#   Mod3 (CapsLock), Mod4, Mod5 (Scroll). 
#

# The release modifier is not a standard X modifier, but you can  
# use it if you want to catch release events instead of press events

# By defaults, xbindkeys does not pay attention with the modifiers
# NumLock, CapsLock and ScrollLock.
# Uncomment the lines above if you want to pay attention to them.

#keystate_numlock = enable
#keystate_capslock = enable
#keystate_scrolllock= enable

# Examples of commands:

"xbindkeys_show" 
 control+shift + q
```

Every line beginning with `#` is a comment and won't be read or run by `xbindkeys`.

So far the only line that isn't commented out is:

```
"xbindkeys_show" 
 control+shift + q
```

This excerpt shows the basic syntax of `xbindkeys` commands:

```
"Command to run (in quotes)"
key to associate with command (no quotes)
```

So as you can see:

```
"xbindkeys_show" 
 control+shift + q
```

Runs the command `xbindkeys_show` when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>.

## bind keys to commands..

Now lets try binding a few keys.  I recommend clearing the entire default file so that it's blank.  It contains preset key bindings you probably don't want.

Now lets say you want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to open your browser.  First you need to know what the name or *keysym* of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> is.  As mentioned earlier you can use `xbindkeys -k` to find the name of a key or keys, but there is an easier way.  For simple combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> you can just use:

```
Control+b
```

A lot easier isn't it!

Now find the command for your favorite browser:

- For Firefox: `firefox`
- For Chromium: `chromium-browser`
- For Opera:  `opera`

Remember the syntax from earlier?  The `xbindkeys` command to launch Firefox (or your other favorite browser) when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> is:

```
"firefox"
Control+b
```

Now put that in your config file and save it.  Now you might notice your command doesn't work yet, that's because `xbindkeys` isn't running.  To start it just run `xbindkeys` from a terminal.  Your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> should now start your browser!

## bind keys to other keys..

If you want a key on your keyboard to call a different key on your keyboard, you will need an extra piece of software as `xbindkeys` does not support this on it's own.  I know of two programs which we can use, `xdotool` and `xte`.  I prefer `xte` so I'm going to use that.

Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation
```

The syntax for `xte` is like this:

```
xte 'command key/mousebutton/xyCoordinates'
```

Examples:

- To call a single key press:  `xte 'key keyName'`
- To call a key combination:  `xte 'keydown keyName' 'keydown secondKeyName' 'keyup keyName' 'keyup secondKeyName`
- To call a mouse button:  `xte 'mouseclick buttonNumber'`  (We'll discuss finding button numbers a little latter)
- To move the mouse:  `xte 'mousemove xCoordinate yCoordinate'`
- And more! Read `man xte`

Now that you know the command for simulating key presses you can call it from your `xbindkeys` script, like this:

```
"xte 'key b'"
Control+b
```

As you might guess, this calls `xte 'key b'` when we press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, which would enter a <kbd>b</kbd> into any document you might be currently working on.

I thing to note however is that `xbindkeys` and `xte` don't always work very well together.  Sometimes you have to press the keys *exactly* at the same time to get output, other times it works just fine.  This may or may not have to do with system configuration and/or hardware.. I'm not sure.  See [maggotbrain's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/257497/44179) for a more reliable way of binding keys to other keys.

## bind mouse buttons to commands..

You can also use `xbindkeys` to bind mouse buttons to commands (and thence keyboard shortcuts, see above). The basic format for mouse buttons should be familiar to you now:

```
" [command to run]  "
b:n
```

Where `[command to run]` is the command you want to run and `n` the number of the mouse button you want to use for that command.

If you don't know the number of your mouse button you can use `xev` to find out what it is:

```
xev | grep button
```

The output will be something like this:

```
user@host:~$ xev | grep button
    state 0x10, button 1, same_screen YES
    state 0x110, button 1, same_screen YES
    state 0x10, button 2, same_screen YES
    state 0x210, button 2, same_screen YES
    state 0x10, button 3, same_screen YES
    state 0x410, button 3, same_screen YES
```

When I press each of my mouse buttons.

For example:

```
" firefox "
b:2
```

Launches firefox when I press my middle mouse button.

Comment: Is it possible with xbindkeys to map Meta+C/V for copy/paste and Meta+Space for language switch?

Comment: is there a way of attaching a sequence of characters to a single key, e.g. attach "equation" to the volume-up key?

Answer (score 74):

## Xev and xmodmap

Changing key bindings using `xev` and `xmodmap`.

Both command line applications are available by default, so there is no need to install additional software.

**Xev**  *"creates a window and then asks the X server to send it events whenever anything happens to the window  (such  as  it  being  moved, resized, typed in, clicked in, etc.)."* [xev man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xev.1.html)

**xmodmap** is a *"program is used to edit and display the  keyboard  modifier map and keymap table that are used by client applications to convert event keycodes into keysyms."* [xmodmap man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xmodmap.1.html)

The following example will remap the <kbd>Caps_Lock</kbd> key to the behavior of the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key (Many vi/vim users find this to be a useful keyboard mapping).

### Using xev

**Start the `xev` application from a terminal window** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>).  It may be useful to grep its output like  `xev | grep -i key`

The application will initialize, display a number of lines, and start a small window with a box.
Keep the `xev` application window in focus, and press the key whose properties/behavior that you wish to use.

- **Press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key**

In the terminal window, you will see several lines of output. Make note of 3rd line returned. This will contain the name of the property you wish to move to the other key.

```
KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x3e00001,
    root 0x256, subw 0x0, time 16245388, (616,73), root:(1487,535),
    state 0x10, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
```

In this case, the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key(keycode 9) uses the name *"Escape"*.

- **Press the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key**

This time we are looking for the keycode that <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is using.

Again, note the 3rd line:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x256, subw 0x0, time 94702774, (862,151), root:(1733,613),
    state 0x10, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe5, Caps_Lock), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 9
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
```

### Using xmodmap

Now that we have obtained the information on the keys that we wish to change from `xev`, we will use `xmodmap` to modify the keymaps.
From the command terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), run the following commands:

- This command modifies the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to use the same behavior as <kbd>Esc</kbd>

  ```
   xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape"
  ```

You can also remap it to basically any key, here it is remapped to the `p` key

```
    xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = p"
```

- This option prints the current keymap table as expressions into the file `~/.Xmodmap`

  ```
   xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap
  ```

Activate the changes(for this login session only) with following command:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Making changes persistent across reboots:

- If it doesn't exist, create a file in your home folder called `.xinitrc`.

  ```
    touch ~/.xinitrc
  ```
- Place the following line in the file and save the file:

  ```
    xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
  ```

#### Modifying keys with different state behaviors

(such as <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>)

- Obtain the keymap table for the modifier keys (output abbreviated here)

  ```
    $ xmodmap -pm
    shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
    mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
  ```

If you wanted to change, for example, the behavior of the period on  <kbd>Del</kbd>/<kbd>Period</kbd> key on the number keypad, to a comma, use the following command:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 91 mod2 = KP_Delete comma"
```

Note that this is using `mod2` keymapping to change key behavior when the modifier <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> is pressed.
The syntax for this is:

```
xmodmap -e "<KEYCODE> <MODIFIER> = <behaviour> <behaviour_with_modifier>"
```

[Resource](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys/24930#24930)

Comment: +1! I have a korean keyboard atm with no alt-gr key, and I needed it so your answer was very helpful to get it working. For future reference, and as the alt-gr key isn't the simplest to set, here is the command (I used the hanja key, which has the code 130) : xmodmap -e "keycode 130 = ISO_Level3_Shift Multi_key ISO_Level3_Shift Multi_key"

Comment: Running `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` freezes my terminal on Ubuntu 20.04. Any thoughts?

Comment: @SaTa Thanks for the comment. I would recommend asking a new question providing relevant details. I've never had an issue myself. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: This works but not the startup instructions for me.  Apparently it's a pain to get it to startup and you practically have to use kbd instead of xmodmap these days... https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04

Answer (score 47):

By default (This is just to complement the Excellent answer by Seth), Ubuntu (In this example I am using 16.04) has 2 categories that come by default in the System Settings:

To go to the System Settings, on the **Top Right** click on the **Gear** icon:

[image]

Then select **System Settings**:

[image]

Here you will find 2 options that can send you to the Shortcut Creation section.

[image]

If you select **Text Entry** you will have to select the **Keyboard Settings** Link on the Bottom Right which would send you directly to the Shortcuts options.

[image]

If you select the **Keyboard** option, you would have to click on the **Shortcuts** Tab

[image]

After arriving at the Shortcuts tabs, you would select the **Custom Shortcuts** at the bottom of the list in the left side:

[image]

And then click on the **Plus Sign** at the bottom in order to start creating your very own Shortcut:

[image]

From there on, it's just a matter of you adding the name of the shortcut (Do not confuse the name of the shortcut, for the name of the actual command you will be executing). And below, in the Command field, is where you will put what command will be executed for this shortcut. In the following example I named the Shortcut "Sublime Text 3" to know what that specific shortcut relates to. And on the command field I added the actual command which is `subl`.

[image]

You will end up with the following on screen that shows that, since the shortcut does not yet have a key or key combination assigned, it is Disabled by default:

[image]

We would then click on the "Disabled" message in order to add a key combination to it:

[image]

In this part, I assign the key combination of <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> so that when I press this combination it opens the Sublime Text App.

[image]

After which, you can simply test your combination by pressing the corresponding key combination and seeing the app open:

[image]

NOTE: For special combinations like the one to kill the X Server, I suggest visiting the following link: [How do I enable Ctrl-Alt-Backspace to kill the X server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367983/how-do-i-enable-ctrl-alt-backspace-to-kill-the-x-server/446506#446506)

Comment: I'm on 13.10 and I don't have this 'Text Entry' icon in my System Settings at all.  :(

Comment: Hi wim can you provide a link to an image that shows your system settings.

Comment: Sadly now we're at 15.04 this answer is a garbled mess. Keyboard Layout is gone, and with it the ability to Kill X Server. The screenshots mix up pre-13.04 (who cares!?!) and later screenshots, and someone inserted them in the wrong place, so "click the Options at the bottom right)" is far from the actual, obsolete, screenshot. :-(

Comment: @skierpage That is why I made this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/367983/how-do-i-enable-ctrl-alt-backspace-to-kill-the-x-server/446506#446506 hope it helps.

Comment: ```If you click on the Options button at the bottom right (Found on 13.04 or previous versions)...``` Where is the options button on versions >13.04?

Comment: @dinosaur I think it is a bit late to be asking about 13.04 or less with 6 versions after it already build. If there is an option, right now I would not even remember.

Comment: I'm asking about versions *after* 13.04. In your answer you refer to an options button found on the lower right of the "Keyboard Layout" window in 13.04 and previous versions but you don't say where that button is for versions later than 13.04. Does it exist?

Comment: @dinosaur Holy crap you are right. They sure changed that A LOT. Let me do the whole answer again but based on 16.04. I believe many changes were done between 13.04 up to 16.04 and that button moved a lot until it disappear.

Comment: For whatever reason on 19.10 this worked for remapping a key in Terminal but not in browsers.  Weird...

Answer (score 22):

Go to **System Settings** → **Keboard**, select **Shortcuts** tab and add a new custom shortcut for your browser. If your default brouser is Firefox, use `firefox` for in command field; if your default brouser is Firefox, use `chromium-browser`, and so on:

[image: add custom shortcut]

Comment: Thanks.  See also my own answer for some peculiarities about actually setting the keys.  Had me mystified at first even though I was in the right place.

Comment: But this does not work in my case. Ubuntu (for some reason) won't let me set the shortcut keys at all! I have followed till step 4 (as shown in the pic). Am I missing out on something?

Comment: I prefer this answer to those available on the duplicate question.

Comment: @VaibhavKaushal: in Step 5 you have to click on the right on "deactivated" then do the shortcut you like, which will be shown there immediately

Comment: Rebooting may be needed for the changes to take effect

Answer (score 20):

You can create complex (multi-key) keyboard shortcuts by installing [AutoKey](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/autokey-gtk/) from the software center.  Unlike xmodmap, AutoKey doesn't rebind the actual keys on your keyboard; it runs in the background and intercepts your defined keyboard shortcuts, then sends simulated keypresses to your applications.

The first time you launch AutoKey, it will start the service in the background (the notification icon hasn't been updated for unity, so there's no visual indication).  Once it's running, you can bring up the configuration interface by running the launcher again:

[image]

Now open Edit > Preferences and select "Automatically start AutoKey at login" to make sure that your shortcuts work whenever you are logged in.

### Mapping a keyboard shortcut to another keyboard shortcut

1. Select File > New > Phrase .
2. Make sure "Paste using" is set to "Keyboard".
3. Type the keys you want to map *to* in the text box.

   - Special (non-character) keys are represented with the codes documented [here](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Special-Keys).
   - If you type multiple keys, they'll be sent in sequence unless you place a `+` between them (e.g. `<ctrl>+c` would copy in most applications; `<ctrl>+c<ctrl>+n<ctrl>+v` would create a new document containing the selection; `<shift>+ubuntu` would type the text "Ubuntu")
4. Press the "Set" button next to "Hotkey". This will bring up a dialog that allows you to determine the key combination you want to map *from*:

   [image]
5. Select File > Save

An example of a completed configuration (which sends `<enter>` when you press `<ctrl>+m`) looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Note: Currently, Debian (where Ubuntu gets the AutoKey package) is not maintaining their AutoKey package. For current installation instructions, see: https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Installing

Comment: I get the script "Enter" encountered an error. It literally contains nothing but <enter>. (Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

Install a program called XKeyCaps.  To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install xkeycaps
```

Once installed, you can do xkeycaps at the prompt to run the program.  Once it runs, choose the right keyboard layout, and click OK

[image]

Then when you get the keyboard on the screen right click the key that you want, in your case its the <kbd>S</kbd>, and choose exchange keys.

[image]

Make sure to add the line below to your sessions so it autostarts each time you boot up.

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap-`uname-n`
```

<sup>Source: [UFM ytsejam1138](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1121475)</sup>

Comment: Is `uname-n` supposed to be `uname -n`?

Comment: According to the source its `unmae-n`.  I don't have access to an Ubuntu machine to test, but once I do, I'll check further.

Comment: Can this exchange the fn key with another key (not fn key is undetectable by things as xev)?

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to remap keys, the other answers are great.

However, there's another way to approach it. [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/) is a keyboard macro processor that allows you to associate any key/modifier combination with a script that can do almost anything you can do from your keyboard and a lot more.

AutoKey has a script recorder and a simple way to enter basic key sequences, but its scripts are written in Python and can do almost anything you can code.

The simplest way to use it is to have it send keystrokes to your applications/desktop.  When used this way, the system/applications cannot tell that it's not you typing, so there is no API or other interface needed, they just do what "you" typed.

AutoKey can also process phrases. When you type a triggering character string, it can substitute new text for that string (either immediately or after you type a separator character like a newline or tab.)

It also has window filters so that you can restrict a particular phrase or script to only run in particular types of windows (like ones that have Mozilla in the title so they work only in things like Firefox or Thunderbird).

AutoKey currently has Gtk and Qt versions.

Edits:

[Installation Guide](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Installing)

[User Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/autokey-users)
Active user forum.

There are a number of example scripts in the wiki. Because it's primarily a GUI app with a lot of options, examples would require a lot of screenshots and a whole article.

I have a phrase defined so that when I type "*Jmail!*", it instantly replaces it with my rather long email address.

I wrote a script that is triggered by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> which is only active in windows that have "Mozilla" in their title.  Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> brings up the (Firefox or Thunderbird) print dialog, selects Print to File and then fills in the name of the next available print file in my print queue (I number them 01, 02, ... and the script reads the queue directory, finds the last file number and increments it by 1).  I use it with my duplex printing emulation software ([duplexpr](http://sourceforge.net/projects/duplexpr/)) to eliminate a ton of keystrokes and mouse movements.

I have seen some other scripts from gamers that let them access information about their character and resources very quickly so they can stay focused on the action.

Comment: Could you add some information about installing it and maybe using it too?  That would be awesome!

Comment: AutoKey has been partially migrated from code.google to GitHub. See https://github.com/autokey/autokey . There is also a Python 3 branch - https://github.com/guoci/autokey-py3 .

Comment: The current version of AutoKey is at https://github.com/autokey/autokey The Python 2 branch has been depreciated.

Answer (score 8):

## **Using xkb**

`xkb` is the X Keyboard extension. It is responsible for mapping your keyboard's keys to their designated function.
`xkb` symbols can be found in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`. The modifier keys are mapped in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`.

Say, I need to switch the functions of `Caps Lock` and `Left Control` keys. These changes are required to the `pc` file:

```
key <CAPS> {        [ Control_L             ]       };
key <LCTL> {        [ Caps_Lock             ]       };
```

In order to apply the new mappings you need to clear out `xkb`’s cache from `/var/lib/xkb`:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
```

Now, just restart your X session and you are good to go.

Source: https://radu.cotescu.com/remapping-keys-in-ubuntu-14.04/

**Edit:**
Doing an `ls` inside the `symbols` directory gives this:

```
af        cm            gn       kz              nec_vndr    sk
al        cn            gr       la              ng          sn
altwin    compose       group    latam           nl          sony_vndr
am        ctrl          hp_vndr  latin           no          srvr_ctrl
apl       cz            hr       level3          nokia_vndr  sun_vndr
ara       de            hu       level5          np          sy
at        digital_vndr  ie       lk              olpc        terminate
az        dk            il       lt              pc          th
ba        ee            in       lv              ph          tj
bd        empty         inet     ma              pk          tm
be        epo           iq       macintosh_vndr  pl          tr
bg        es            ir       mao             pt          tw
br        et            is       md              ro          typo
brai      eurosign      it       me              rs          tz
bt        fi            jp       mk              ru          ua
bw        fo            ke       ml              rupeesign   us
by        fr            keypad   mm              se          uz
ca        fujitsu_vndr  kg       mn              sgi_vndr    vn
capslock  gb            kh       mt              sharp_vndr  xfree68_vndr
cd        ge            kpdl     mv              shift       za
ch        gh            kr       nbsp            si
```

The mappings inside the file `ru` are based on the Russian standard keyboard. The `macintosh_vndr` folder contains the mappings for Apple keyboards. In a nutshell, this approach is so much versatile. Go ahead and play with it :)

Comment: You mentioned 2 files. What file are the changes made to? :)

Comment: I mentioned only one file - `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`.

Comment: My bad. Took me a second look to realize that the first path was a folder, not a file. Edited to make it a tad more obvious :)

Answer (score 7):

**USING KEYBOARD KEYS AS MOUSE BUTTONS**

You may want to map a keyboard key to a mouse button.  If you want to click using a keyboard key (useful if you have a macbook or a bad trackpad button) then you can do the following.

1. install some utilities:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install x11-utils xkbset x11-xserver-utils
   ```
2. find the keycode for the key you want to map:

   - type `xev | grep keycode` in the terminal
   - press the key of interest and a line like this will appear:

     ```
     state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
     ```
3. using the keycode, remap the key to do the same as the left mouse button:

   - `xkbset m`
   - `xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Pointer_Button1"`

`Pointer_Button3` is the right mouse button and `Pointer_Button2` is the middle.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that it is under the 'keyboard' application.

If you bring that up, you can then change shortcuts as needed...

change is a bit strange on first use.  You click over on the right (the column that has ctrl-alt-T, Disabled, etc.  then click the actual keys, eg <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> that you want.  You'll see the new key sequence appear now in that space.  Close the window (or click away) and the new shortcut will now work.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut already exist as WWW, just change it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.  No need to create a new one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM)

CCSM lets you change some system keyboard shortcuts.

To install it, use the Software Center, or this command:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

### For example

I used it to change the "Window spread" shortcut from the default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, like on Windows 10. From [my answer on another thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/859724/301745):

> 1. Run CCSM from the Dash.
> 2. Go to **Window management** -> **Scale** -> **Bindings** tab ->     **Initiate Window Picker**
> 3. Click the keyboard shortcut (`<Super>w` on your PC, but `<Super>Tab` in this screenshot).
>
>    [image: CCSM - Window management - Scale]
> 4. Click **Grab key combination**, press the desired key(s), then click OK.
>
>    [image: Edit Initiate Window Picker]

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to press Print Screen to save a screen shot using the `gnome-screenshot` application, as in Mint

But I wanted to do it using terminal, not GUI, as I want to make it default while creating a custom ISO using `squashfs` tools.

First I installed gnome-screenshot using command

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-screenshot
```

Then I assigned the custom shortcut using **Settings -> Keyboard ->
 Custom shortcuts** -> Add (+) button ->

In the dialog:

- Name : Screen shot
- Command: gnome-screentshot

Press Add Button

Then press the <kbd>Print screen</kbd> key.

Key is now bound, and I can save the screen shots as required.
But not using terminal, it's the GUI way

Then I installed `dconf-editor` using

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

And search for `gnome-screenshot`
I find my custom key bindings at this path

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/
```

Values of keys are:

- binding 'Print'
- command 'gnome-screenshot'
- name 'print screen'

Now I copy these and delete the GUI custom shortcut key

I open terminal and type these commands

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/command "'gnome-screenshot'"
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/binding  "'Print'"
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/name "'print screen'"
```

And voila

Now I can save screen shots without any GUI only using `dconf` and terminal. I don't need `dconf-editor` any more either, it was just installed to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Kevin's solution (the xmodmap approach) on ubuntu 18.04. It didn't work in my case. Yet this procedure made it work finally:

- copy `xmodmap .Xmodmap` in a file called `.xsession` rather than `.xinitrc`.
- change the permissions of the file (right-click, properties, permission tab, changing the permissions to "read and write" and ticking the box down the window)
- add a startup application with `/home/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/.xsession` as command.