# How to make Caps Lock change keyboard layout without delay?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, capslock

I use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to change keyboard layout since the first year with Linux.

Now, somewhere in the last year some patch added something so now it waits for ~300ms before changing the layout. And if I hit any key before that time ends it doesn't work. AFAIU it's somehow related to using <kbd>Meta</kbd>/<kbd>Win</kbd> both as modifier and as key. Is that interval tweakable? I don't use it as a modifier at all.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1462333&page=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols
sudo cp capslock capslock.bak
sudo sed -i 's#key <CAPS> {\t\[\tISO_Next_Group,\tCaps_Lock\t]\t};#key <CAPS> {        repeat=no, [ ISO_Next_Group, Caps_Lock ] };#' capslock
```

#### Update:

You also have to **release the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>** before pressing another key.

Related:
https://askubuntu.com/q/264127/20275

Comment: Great to hear if that's working for you! btw, have you perused [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do/254425), yet ?

Comment: Not yet :) I'm familiar with xbindkeys, xev and xmodmap. Should I?

Answer (score 2):

I use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to trigger the keyboard layout switch.

When using both layouts, I *very* frequently switch back and forth, and the switch seems *instantaneous*. That is, I never experience a hang (and I'm a fast touch typist - on both layouts).

Maybe worth considering?

Comment: Agree to that. Perhaps worth mentioning is that keyboard layouts settings can be found in: System Settings >> Keyboard >> Layout Settings (which is a tiny link in the bottom left corner of Keyboard window, Typing tab), it is not in Shortcuts... That's assuming you use Ubuntu 12.

Comment: Plus, it's possible (can't remember off the top of my head exactly how) to put a flag in the top bar indicating your layout... you can even customize your flag (and/or found your very own separatist nation state and hoist your own personalized flag!) ... ;)

Comment: I appreciate your effort and suggestion but I strongly disagree. I need the Caps Lock only.

Comment: Again, I don't understand those who upvote this solution since it's forcing **your** habits to **someone else**. I didn't ask about any alternatives.

Comment: I'm so disappointed because if the situation doesn't change half the bounty is going to be awarded to this answer automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Though not a fan of apple, the observation in a [SOLVED thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2571421?start=0&tstart=0) (on apple.com) that switching on the Caps Lock light (or keeping it lit? whatever... ) *could* be causing a delay might be a pointer into the right direction: the work-around suggested in the thread involves using 3rd-party software to **emulate** certain **key combinations**.

What comes to mind as an equivalent in the Linux world is **`xdotool`** (see the [**man** page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html), which has some basic examples). Specifically to your case, you may want to try sth like **`xdotool`**`key`**`Caps_Lock`** as used in yet another [SOLVED thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1738995.html) (on ubuntuforums.org).

According to my own experience (unless you're willing to *really* go a level deeper) you'll have to play around with different key combinations and `xdotool` to find the magic combination which really does work smoothly. But definitely worth giving it a try!

Comment: Read the updated question.