# Change language after button release

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, shortcuts, language-support, system-settings

Is there a way to change language when i press Alt+Shift, and then I release the last key? At the moment language is changed after I press the last key, before I release it. Because of that many shortcuts in many programs don't work.

Comment: Not sure if possible but you should look into xmodmap.

Comment: Maybe you'll find something useful there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/261449/how-to-make-caps-lock-change-keyboard-layout-without-delay