# How can I remap Control+m to Enter?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap, shortcut-keys

I'd like to remap some key behaviors globally.

For example:

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> -> <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Is there any tool equivalent to Keyremap4Macbook ? Or is it possible to remap by using Xmodmap?

I've tried AutoHotkey, but it didn't work well with Guake. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/257497#257497

Answer (score 5):

Remapping keys with the control modifier using xmodmap is possible, but unreliable.  For example:

`xmodmap -e "keycode 58 Shift_L Control_L = m M Return"`

is a legal key mapping, and it will work in the terminal, and in a handful of GUI applications (those using Xt), but not in Gtk or Qt apps, which generally intercept the control key directly, bypassing the mapping.

---

If you're willing to install and run AutoKey, you can configure it to do what you want.  Install the `autokey-gtk` package and configure a phrase like this:

[image: Phrase=Enter, Paste=Keyboard, Hotkey=Ctrl-M]