# Global keyboard shortcut for copy, cut and paste

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, paste

**How can I define a global shortcuts for copy, cut and paste?**

I'm used to Mac's <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for copy and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for paste. They are global, so I can use them interchanging data between CLI and GUI apps.

How can one configure global shortcuts, e.g <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (copy) and <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (paste) in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Have you tried the same in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. `⊞ Win+C` pops the "search photos" screen.

Comment: Try `⌘+C` in Ubuntu

Comment: I don't have a `⌘` key - it's a windows laptop keyboard with a `⊞` key.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203?noredirect=1#comment383753_300203), and see if it helps.

Comment: @Mitch thanks, but I don't see how your answer allows me to create global copy and paste shortcut that would work for the terminal, too.

Comment: Is the standard configuration really that bad? Ctrl-C generally and Ctrl-Shift-C in terminal? (same with V for paste).

Comment: @Anake Yes it's really bad when half of time you are using Mac Os :) Anyway, meta key on Linux pretty useless button so why not to remap for this actions and use it anywhere. Also want to remap change_input_language to Meta+Space, but it also looks impossible.

Answer (score 3):

These are global shortcuts that work out of the box (tested with Debian 8.2) in terminals and GUI applications:

- copy: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>
- paste: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>
- cut: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

I didn't test it but to change these shortcuts you could try: [Use Shift+Insert to paste from clipboard in gnome-terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397972/use-shiftinsert-to-paste-from-clipboard-in-gnome-terminal)