# Use Shift+Insert to paste from clipboard in gnome-terminal?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I would like to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>
 and have that execute a paste from the clipboard (the thing that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies to) inside of gnome-terminal.

In 13.10, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> pastes from the selection buffer (the thing that selecting text writes to). In Libre Office, Chrome, and Firefox, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> pastes from the clipboard. I would thus like to configure gnome-terminal to do the same.

I would not like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. EDIT: I phrased this poorly. I would still like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> but I did not want people to post that as a solution. The reason why I would like to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> is because a program I use sends the keys <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> assuming that it will paste.

Unfortunately, in gnome-terminal there is no setting for this under *Edit → Profile Preferences → Compatibility*, nor is there under *Edit → Keyboard Shortcuts*.

The only other related post I can find is:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/266096/how-to-restore-proper-x-clipboard-behaviour-shiftinsert-in-12-10
which I think prefers the opposite of what I prefer and is probably happy now with the change.

Comment: Do you want both Ctrl+Shift+V and Shift+Ins to paste the clipboard in Gnome Terminal?

Comment: I don't understand... I do use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> in my terminal to paste clipboard. And it's a (almost) freshly installed Ubuntu 13.10. The only extra thing I remember installing is `vim`.

Comment: @GabrielF strange. Thanks for the information. I will do some more checking.

Comment: I wonder who had the "brilliant" idea of changing a shortcut almost universal... and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a simple workaround for what you need.

1. First you will have to install [xdotool [image: Install xdotool]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xdotool).
2. Then launch the Keyboard configuration `gnome-control-center keyboard`:
   (Go to Shortcuts → Custom shortcuts)

   [image]
3. Click on "+"  and add a name like "Paste into terminal" and the command

   ```
   xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+shift+v
   ```

   [image]
4. Then choose <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> as the key binding:

   [image]

Because of a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1243532), you will have to logout and log back in so the shortcut can take effect.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in 18.04, the new combo does nothing.  Pasting that `xdotool` command directly into the terminal does work, however.

Answer (score 20):

There is a relatively simple answer:

1. Open Gnome Terminal.
2. Open *Edit → Keyboard Shortcuts*.
3. Click on the old "Ctrl+Shift+V" shortcut for Paste until it changes to *New accelerator*, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.
4. Close the Preferences window.
5. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> should now paste the clipboard.

Comment: This even works in Cinnamon (which also uses gnome-terminal). Saved my day, +1 :)

Comment: I wonder who had the "brilliant" idea of changing a shortcut almost universal... and why?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in 18.04, the new combo does nothing (but Ctrl+Shift+V works after changing it back).

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then why not just change that paste hotkey to <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd> under Edit > Keyboard shortcuts?

I installed gnome-terminal on lubuntu 13.10 and I have that option (see screenshot I already changed it there). If you don't have it you might try to change that setting in `gconf-editor`, see the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: How? I don't see that shortcut under there. Are you sure it's there for 13.10? Which submenu do you see it ("Launchers", "Navigation", ...)?

Comment: @XuWang I have that option on lubuntu 13.10. Is the gnome-terminal different for ubuntu 13.10? I updated my answer.