# How to map a character sequence to a key in xkb?

Tags: 13.04, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am making a keyboard layout in xkb for Punjabi language. The default ones are outdated. In windows I could assign a keyboard key to a sequence of Unicode characters. But in xkb I think I cannot. But in some Arabic layouts it has been done. I want the mapping to be Punjabi specific only and do not want to ruin my default English mapping. e.g. I have assigned " ਾ"(sounds like 'aa',Unicode 0A3E) to 'w' and want to assign 'W' to " ਾਂ"(sounds like 'aan',Unicode 0A3E+0A02)",
which is composed of two Unicode characters " ਾ"(Unicode 0A3E) + " ਂ"(Unicode 0A02).

Can anyone help me,please?

Comment: See if my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#comment383753_300203), might help you.

Comment: 13.04?  That was end-of-life long ago.  Upgrading to a supported version of Ubuntu might fix the problem in the first place ("The default ones are outdated.").

Comment: Even in the newer version its a issue

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not possible, although [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43078) describes a clever workaround.  Basically, that's not what xkb is designed to do; your question is flawed in presuming that xkb is the correct software to solve your problem.