# Keyboard shortcuts with multiple non-modifier keys

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there any way to use a combination of keys such as:

```
Ctrl+Spc+j
```

as a shortcut in Ubuntu? Note that the combination above includes **two non-modifier** keys: `Spc` and `j`.

As an example, I would like to map use the above combination for `"Move window one workspace to the left"`

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#comment383753_300203), and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use more than one non modifier keys in a shortcut your keyboard needs to support n-Key rollover. For a technical description of what that is read [this article](http://blog.controlspace.org/2010/08/n-key-rollover-what-it-is-and-how-to.html).
 Around the middle there is a text field and instructions to test your keyboard. My keyboard dropped half the alphabet, so I can't tell you what to do next, sorry :-(

Edit : I did some research and the only way to achieve something close to what you are looking (that I could find) is [autokey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/wiki/Overview). Although not a "pure" shortcut solution, I think you can script it to perform the action you desire.

Comment: I have two keyboards: the `Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000` and the `Kinesis Advantage Contoured Keyboard`. Both passed the tests on that website, but I am unable to define keyboard shortcuts with multiple non-modifier keys.