# Remap dead_diaresis(?) to Ctrl

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I have some problem with my left little finger. So I'm trying to remap the key which looks like this: [image]

with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button. That part I managed. Now I want to place that key on the caps lock key instead. That's the part where I am stuck.

This is my xmodmap-file:

```
clear control
keycode 35 = Control_R
add control = Control_R Control_L
clear Lock
keycode 66 = dead_diaeresis
```

And this is what `xev` shows me when currently pressing the key in the picture:

```
KeyPress event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xc3, subw 0x0, time 11475613, (392,225), root:(393,308),
    state 0x0, keycode 35 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xc3, subw 0x0, time 11475701, (392,225), root:(393,308),
    state 0x4, keycode 35 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

And this is what xev shows me currently when pressing Caps Lock:

```
KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xc3, subw 0x0, time 11549397, (493,363), root:(494,446),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xfe57, dead_diaeresis), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 a8) "¨"
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xc3, subw 0x0, time 11549493, (493,363), root:(494,446),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xfe57, dead_diaeresis), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 a8) "¨"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Take a look at my [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#comment383753_300203), see if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunatly not. But I did solve it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, mostly. I can't write chars with diaeresis like ë or ü, but I don't do that anyway. My theory is that I can't use AltGr and Caps Lock in the same time. But I don't know.

Anyway, this is my .Xmodmap file:

```
! Remap Ctrl to the ^ key
clear control
keycode 35 = Control_R
add control = Control_R Control_L

! Remap ~ (and ^ with a shift) to Caps Lock, AltGr don't seem to work :-/
clear Lock
keycode 66 = asciitilde dead_circumflex asciitilde asciitilde asciitilde dead_caron asciitilde
```