# Terminal: Replacing Ctrl+r with Ctrl+k

Tags: gnome-terminal, shortcut-keys, terminator

I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> for searching command history in the terminal but this keyboard shortcut is not comfortable for me.

I would prefer using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

How can I update this keyboard shortcut?

(Updating to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> in addition to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> is also an option)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/313589/changing-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the shell builtin command "bind" for that.  What you specifically want is:

bind  '"\C-k":"\C-r"'

Put that in your ~/.bashrc file and it should work each time you open up a shell.  For more details checkout the bind section [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html).

Comment: And in ZSH it's: bindkey "^K" history-incremental-search-backward

Answer (score 1):

Check this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119991/bash-call-script-with-customized-keyboard-shortcuts) about a similar problem.

But my advice is to keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> as is and get used to, because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> is used to erase from the cursor to the end of the line which is a very useful shortcut.