# Ubuntu shortcuts vs OSx shortcuts

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm just trying Ubuntu as I'm slowly but surely getting tired of OSX and it's operating systems released every few months with a lot of problems.

One thing that I find quite frustrating when switching to a new system is the shortcuts, which I got used to - especially for Terminal - most of which work similar, but some of them (ones I use the most) differ.

I've seen this post [Terminal: Replacing Ctrl+r with Ctrl+k](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581916/terminal-replacing-ctrlr-with-ctrlk) and understand that in order to change shortcut for terminal I need to add it to the ~/.bashrc file in the format:

```
bind '"\C-k":"\C-r"'
```

Does anyone know what combination should be used to call `reset` as a combination of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> (on OSX it works as as <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>, but hence PCs don't have `Cmd` - `Alt` is in the same place)?

Answer (score 0):

If by **reset**, you mean **clear** the terminal, then in Gnome Terminal, it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> .

Comment: Thanks @Progrock - it's not just `clear` - it's actually `reset` that I'm after - on OSX it's `Cmd + k` - it resets the session - difference being with `clear` only clearing window, but if you scroll up - you'll still see previous commands, while `reset` wipes them out.

Comment: Oh, you want to set a shortcut for **reset**, try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25077/how-to-really-clear-the-terminal