# How can I rebind Print Screen to Delete?

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, remapping, xkb, print-screen

I'm running Xubuntu Raring Ringtail. Using xkbcomp, I used the following commands (I can go into more detail as to the context and what command I use, if it's relevant), which successfully remapped my Delete key to End and my Insert key to Home, but all it seems to do is render the Print Screen key inert, rather than making it Delete.

`replace key <PRSC> { [ Delete ] };` `replace key <DELE> { [ End ] };` `replace key <INS> { [ Home ] };`

Is there another method by which I can make Prt Sc on my keyboard perform the Delete function?

**Edit:** Even though xkeycaps couldn't give me the keycode, I used xkbprint to get the keycode for my PrtSc key and tried `xmodmap -e "keycode 107 = Delete Delete"` which did the same thing: made PrtSc inert. To be more precise, it actually flashes the cursor in a terminal or the input box here. So I think it's doing something other than delete; I just don't know the secret word other than `Delete` to make a program do what I want.

Comment: See my post [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#comment383753_300203), see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but the few Sony keyboards they have do not match mine. There are too many keyboards to sift through to find one that matches up in the relevant ways.