# How can I remap "special" keys in xkb?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, configuration, keyboard-layout, xkb

I've been trying to migrate my keyboard mapping from xmodmap to xkb, but I'm having some trouble. I can see where to modify the "normal" keys, in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbol/us` for me, but this file seems devoid of "special" keys, including modifiers.

The full remapping that I wish to achieve is:

- Swap <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- Replace <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- Replace <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> with <kbd>'</kbd>
- Replace <kbd>'</kbd> with <kbd>/</kbd>
- Right blank key (keycode 97) to <kbd>Menu</kbd>
- Left blank key (keycode 92) to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> encodings:

  - keycode 20 = minus underscore minus underscore endash emdash
  - keycode 60 = period greater period greater ellipsis
  - <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> control brightness
  - keycode 148 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown
  - keycode 179 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#300203), see if it helps.

Comment: @Mitch I actually did see that already, but as far as I can tell that is to create Xmodmaps? I already have an Xmodmap (which I find much more transparent than xkb), but I'm trying to move to xkb for several reasons: to have specific simultaneous keymaps for multiple keyboards; and to apply this keymap on startup rather than having to reconnect and trigger with a udev rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to create `AltGr` encodings in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbol/us`, but swap most keys using `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` instead.

(However, I haven't worked out how to map Fn+F5 and Fn+F6 to XF86MonBrightnessDown and XF86MonBrightnessUp yet.)