# Remap "special" Keys on HP keyboard

Tags: keyboard, xorg, hp, xkb, remapping

I bought a new HP notebook (elitebook) with an extremely awful keyboard functionality. For example, I don't have an insert key, but I have a phone-dial and phone-hangup key (right upper corner): [image: HP Keyboard Layout]

The thing is, I am extremely used to the insert key. Therefore I was looking for a way to remap the second key from the right (hangup-key) to the insert key. However, none of the proposed solutions work for me ([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327389/how-can-i-remap-special-keys-in-xkb), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#300203), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys)).

E.g., when I run `xev | grep keycode` and press the desired key, I get the following output:

```
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x4, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0xc, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
```

This seems like that key is mapped to the left ALT key? Trying CTRL+ALT+T confirms that suspicion, as it opens the terminal.

Does anybody have any idea how to map that key to the INSERT key I don't have?

- EDIT *

As requested, the LEFT CTRL and LEFT ALT KEY pressed:

```
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
```

Thanks!

Comment: in the box that you display the output of `xev` which buttons were you actually pressing, exactly? I find strange that the ALT and CTRL are intertwined. When I press any key in `xev` I always get the key down and key up event, so I would expect to see ALT (down), ALT (up)  and then CTRL (down), CTRL (up). In any case, can you also provide the `xev` output of pressing the actual left alt and left ctrl keys? Are they EXACTLY the same?

Comment: also, according to this [link](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/Disabling-End-Call-Call-Answer-Call-and-Share-Screen-buttons/m-p/7578651/highlight/true#M212775) you might be able to lock the function key state by pressing FN+LEFT, and you might get other (or none) behaviour from this key. Also  worth checking.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was off for some time and didn't get here before. Thanks for the response @avila ! I literally only pressed the "hangup key" (second key from the right). I updated the question with the LEFT CTRL and LEFT ALT key pressed :)

Comment: Btw, thanks for the hint @avila with the FN key. I tried that, but it didn't change anything (neither the functionality, nor the xev output...)

Comment: On my last comment I wrote FN+Left, but meant to write FN+Left Shift. (Left shift is also marked as FN LOCK). Did you try that? If it does not work, I can only think of workaround such as mapping a third function to another key, such as RightAlt + Delete = Insert, or something in this direction.

Comment: Yep, tried FN and left shift (read the actual thread you linked). Thanks for your help though! Maybe I need to try the keymapper below. I just tried to avoid installing a third party application.

Comment: how you found a solution? these stupid HP keys are so useless

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Key Mapper...

https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper

[image: Screenshot of Key Mapper]

Install Key Mapper as follows...

```
sudo apt install git python3-setuptools
git clone https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper.git
cd key-mapper; ./scripts/build.sh
sudo apt install ./dist/key-mapper-1.0.0.deb
sudo apt -f install  # install dependencies if necessary
```

Usage instructions are here...

https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper/blob/main/readme/usage.md

Comment: it does not work.