# How to swap left Alt with left Win and use left Alt as 3rd level chooser?

Tags: keyboard-layout, swap, keys

How can i do such things as swap left <kbd>Alt</kbd> with left <kbd>Win</kbd> and use left <kbd>Alt</kbd> as 3rd level chooser?

If I use both the swapping does not take effect but my <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is 3rd level chooser and <kbd>Win</kbd> key opens the run prompt (***?***). Don't know how it is called.
I've tried `xmodmap` to change the keys but without success.

I'm using German (Macintosh) as keyboard layout.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#300203), help?

Comment: I don't think you should need to use xmodmap. In any case, xkb is preferred over xmodmap now (although the documentation is terrible). Do I understand correctly that you want the physical `Alt` key as your 3rd level chooser, and your physical `Win` key to work as the `Alt` modifier? I presume you've modified the system settings? (I run KDE, but I presume that the Unity settings are similar, if that's what you are using?) Can you open the terminal and run `setxkbmap -query`?

Comment: The output is:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     de
variant:    mac
options:    lv3:lalt_switch,altwin:swap_lalt_lwin
Mainly I want to swap Alt and Win key and use the virtual Alt (physical win) as 3rd level chooser. (Sorry about formatting I'm pretty new to the ubuntu community and sorry about grammar)

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut in the 'setxkbmap' command that does exactly that.

```
# Usefule for 'mac' keyboards.
setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_alt_win
```

I find it useful with Mac keyboards. However, it may interfer with other modifications that you do with xkb.