# How to map Ctrl+S in vim on gnome-terminal?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-terminal, vim

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and gnome-terminal 3.4.1.1, and I'm trying to map <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to `:update` in `vim`.

I added this to my vimrc: `map <C-s> :update<CR>`

I also tried adding this to my bashrc: `stty -ixon -ixoff`

However, the terminal still seems to override my keymapping.

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#300203)help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> in a terminal by:

```
stty stop undef
```

You can put this line in your `~/.bashrc` file to make the change permanent. You can also reenable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> with:

```
stty stop ^s
```