# How to permanently switch Caps Lock and Esc

Tags: keyboard-layout

How can I permanently switch the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> key functions in Saucy? I can use this command to do it temporarily (until reboot):

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "caps:swapescape"
```

I tried adding that command as a Startup Application, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I put that command in my ```~/.bashrc``` so it persists between system restarts. (```ctrl:nocaps``` for me, though, for ```tmux```)

Comment: @opyate I would put that command in ~/.profile so that it will run only once after an interactive login.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Another way to do this is through the `dconf-editor`. This method has a few extra steps from `gnome-tweak-tool`, but is useful if you don't want to pull in the dependencies from the tweak tool.

This will allow you to use the `caps:swapescape` syntax and automatically make the change permanent.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

On Ubuntu >20.04, you'll need to run the following - see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248426/what-has-replaced-dconf-tools-for-ubuntu-20-04):

```
sudo apt install dconf-cli dconf-editor
```

After starting the `dconf-editor`, navigate to *org >> gnome >> desktop >> input-sources*

Add the options that you need in `xkb-options`. The option strings are surrounded by single quotes and separated by commas. Be careful not to delete the brackets on the ends.

[image: xkb-options in dconf-editor]

You can use this method to enter most of the traditional xkb options that are no longer available in *System Settings >> Text Entry*. The exception are the settings for switching the keyboard layouts, which currently do not work because of a bug.

For a list of the options and the syntax, use `man 7 xkeyboard-config` in a terminal.

Another common option that could be used is `terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp` to allow <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> to end the X-session.

Comment: +1 for referencing `keyboard-config(7)`, this was what I was looking for.

Comment: You can also do this from the command line, without installing dconf-editor: `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['caps:escape']"`

Comment: Don't run the above command using 'sudo' as this setting seems per user specific.

Comment: Yes, these settings are in the user profile and can be different for different users. You need sudo to install dconf-editor if it's not already installed.

Comment: Note that you need to use `'caps:swapescape'` if you need to *swap* the two keys (instead of just assigning `Esc` to `Caps Lock`).

Comment: or you can do `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:escape']"`

Comment: I [wrote a small script](https://gist.github.com/berkes/05edefafa84c8c5f053e) to toggle this behaviour: handy when a co-worker wants to type something and gets confused by your swapped caps-esc.

Comment: The only working solution with CentOS 7 I've tried.

Comment: This is dependent on the window manager. @jojo's solution is better because it works even when you change your WM like I did.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04, `dconf-tools` is not found, but `sudo apt install dconf-editor` did the trick.

Comment: Stops working after automatic idle logout but works after the restart.
It's better to have this configuration plus @jojo's answer as `alias` for the times when this stops working.

Comment: The solution doesn't work anymore for ubuntu 20.04 as the package `dconf-tools` has been removed. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248426/what-has-replaced-dconf-tools-for-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: If someone else can't get this to work at first (like me), your keyboard might be the problem. I have an Freestyle Pro keyboard and this solution didn't work, tried a different keyboard and it works perfectly.

Comment: @PiDelport How to undo this?

Comment: FWIW, the installation of this tool (with package `dconf-editor` now, instead of `dconf-tools`) allowed me to edit this OK, but making changes to it seemed to have no effect.  Is it something where I need to log out and back in again first, or something?  `setxkbmap` (as mentioned in another answer) had an immediate effect, though I'm unsure whether it will last (a previous attempt with xmodmap would work and then reset within... seconds?  Some short amount of time.  So far, though, it's been working for a few minutes, at least).

Answer (score 125):

A solution that should work for most linux distros:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape
```

Other options are possible:

- `caps:none` to deactivate
- `caps:escape` to make it an additional escape
- `caps:super` to make it an additional super (windows) key.

**To make this work at startup**, you can put it in `~/.profile` as this will only run after the interactive login.

If the switch does not persist between logins (e.g. when suspending your machine) you can also create a `.xinitrc` file in your home directory and put it there. Linux mint 20 on a laptop works impeccable with this option.

---

If above does not persist use */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf* (see `man xorg.conf` DESCRIPTION for all available paths). It should work with Bluetooth keyboards that reconnect after sleep.

```
Section "InputClass"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbOptions" "caps:escape"
EndSection
```

See `man xkeyboard-config`

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 14.04, Unity.

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04 as well

Comment: as of 18.04, putting `setxkbmap` commands in `~/.xsessionrc` and `~/.profile` no longer appear to make settings persist between logins/restarts

Comment: @Conrad.Dean I'm using this in Mint 19 which is based on 18.04 LTS: No problems here.  The settings are not supposed to persist but are loaded at login.

Comment: `~/.profile` is a poor place to put this -- that file is read on every login shell. Put it in a file used when starting X11, like `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession`.

Comment: There seems to be an order of operations that matters as well - this command might have to be run *before* the application you want to affect is open and things like suspending your computer can reset it

Comment: This worked for me; thanks!  Suggestion for further improvement: among your "Other options are possible" section, maybe also list `ctrl:nocaps` and `ctrl:swapcaps`, as those are likely also common use cases.  And/or refer to `man 7 xkeyboard-config` for the full suite of possibilities.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: VSCode on Fedora is absolutely confused by this. Sometimes it needs escape, sometimes not.

Comment: I can only advise against modifying `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` as documented, it broke my system (22.04 LTS), I couldn't boot into GRUB anymore. Had to use a LIVE usb, `chroot` into the filesystem and delete the file.

Answer (score 57):

Okay, found a way to do this using gnome-tweak-tool.

From a terminal, run

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool -y && gnome-tweak-tool
```

You can find an option to swap Caps Lock and Esc in "Typing -> Caps Lock key behavior".

**Update:** In Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 it can be found in Keyboard & Mouse > Additional Layout Options > Caps Lock Behavior (Thanks to Adracus's comment below)

Comment: On Ubuntu 14 the layout of the window is very screwy, but it still works.

Comment: Yes, I think `gnome-tweak-tool` should not be used for this task because there are default tools to do it.

Comment: This is by far the best solution.

Comment: For Ubuntu >18.04 it can be found in `Keyboard & Mouse` > `Additional Layout Options` > `Caps Lock Behavior`

Comment: This worked for me on 19.04. I couldn't get any of the `xmodmap` or `setxkbmap` solutions to persist on 19.04.

Comment: The executable is called `gnome-tweaks` now.

Comment: Recently this setting from tweaks is ignored on my external keyboard (but respected on my laptop) after resuming from suspend with 20.04. I have to select some other option, then reselect "Swap ESC and Caps Lock". Will go for the `setxkbmap` solution now

Comment: I don't see this option in `gnome-tweaks`

Comment: If someone else can't get this to work at first (like me), your keyboard might be the problem. I have an Freestyle Pro keyboard and this solution didn't work, tried a different keyboard and it works perfectly.

Comment: On 22.04 this is still a viable option. Installed `gnome-tweaks` (name changed?). `Keyboard&Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Ctrl position`. There, in my case I chose `Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock`.

Comment: Substituted `gnome-tweaks` and the rest of the instructions worked perfectly on a new install of Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

You can use [xmodmap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xmodmap.1.html) in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) to swap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> with <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

```bsh
xmodmap -e "keycode 9 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock"   #this will make Esc to act as Caps Lock
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape NoSymbol Escape"        #this will make Caps Lock to act as Esc
```

To get this change for every session, after you have run the ​​previous commands create a file called `.xmodmap` with the new keymaps, using the following command:

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.xmodmap
```

Then, create a file called `.xinitrc` in your home directory, containing the following line/command:

```
xmodmap .xmodmap
```

Comment: This does not work under Ubuntu 14.04. I also tried a .xsessionrc file, and it also did not work.

Comment: How do you undo the settings?

Comment: @hlin117  Just clear the content of the `~/.xmodmap` file (by running only `> ~/.xmodmap` in your terminal), then restart your session.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, this makes Escape maps to Caps_Lock but Caps_Lock does not map to Escape.

Comment: Hi, I did this, and it works. However, besides esc being bound to capslock, caps-lock is now bound to both caps-lock _and_ escape. Is it possible that the desktop environment somehow still overrides this? I use KDE

Comment: If capslock key still enables the capslock in addition to functioning as escape key, use `clear Lock` on top of `.xinitrc` file.

Answer (score 21):

Similar to @Radu's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/365628/447353), but compatible with 14.04 (see also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/23493)).

```
xmodmap -e "remove Lock = Caps_Lock"
xmodmap -e "keycode 9 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock"
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape NoSymbol Escape"
xmodmap -pke > ~/.xmodmap
```

If it does not work, replace:

```
xmodmap -e "remove Lock = Caps_Lock"
```

with:

```
xmodmap -e "clear Lock"
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Linux Mint 17.1 (which is based on Ubuntu) :(

Comment: had to change "remove Lock = Caps_Lock" to "clear Lock" for it to work

Answer (score 17):

Go to the gears icon at the top right corner of the screen and do the following:

- Click System Settings → *Keyboard layout* → *Options...* (lower right hand corner) → *Caps lock key behaviour* (4th down).
- Then scroll down and select *Swap ESC and Caps Lock*.

Done!

Comment: This should be the best answer for ubuntu and mint

Comment: Does this do anything in addition to the scripted updates mentioned here? Prefer to do this in a script.

Answer (score 13):

Run this command once in a terminal.  `dconf` should already be installed with gnome 3.

```
dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options" "['caps:swapescape']"
```

Comment: This solution just tested OK on RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Tried that on Ubuntu Jammy, 22.04.3 LTS. It didn't work. Got ```error: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)``` in response.

Answer (score 13):

The *Keyboard Layout* with *Switch Escape and Capslock* answer above is no longer valid on Ubuntu 16.04 and later (was it before? dunno).

In order to avoid the hustle with permissions etc., just switch to root before you start doing the following steps by running `su` in a terminal and entering your root password. Then:

1. Run:

   ```
   cd /etc/default/
   vim keyboard
   ```
2. There you will see the line:

   ```
   XKBOPTIONS=""
   ```

   Change it to:

   ```
   XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape"
   ```
3. Exit Vim with save:

   ```
   :wqa
   ```
4. Reboot.

And that will be *permanent*, I promise. :)

Comment: run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` to make it permanent.

Comment: you don't need to do that if you do what I said.

Comment: In Debian systems, changes in /etc/default/keyboard do not become immediately visible to X.  You should either reboot the system, or use `sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change`.
In order to activate the changes on the console, run `setupcon`(1).

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? The "Reboot" word in particular?

Comment: Can you make capslock behave like Ctrl if you hold it down?

Comment: Working on 20.04

Comment: `sudo sed -i '/XKBOPTIONS=/c\XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape"' /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: Works on 22.04!

Answer (score 11):

For Ubuntu 18.04 and Gnome 3.30 this works for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:swapescape']"
```

Comment: still working on 19.04.

Comment: works for 19.10

Comment: I'm on Pop!_OS 19.10; this is the first thing I've tried that works and survives reboot.

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:escape']"` to keep the regular ESC key (as in: no swapping)

Answer (score 6):

I've built a tool in C specially for this purpose that overcome [many of the issues with the xcape/xmodmap solution](https://github.com/oblitum/caps2esc#history):

- https://github.com/oblitum/caps2esc

It does a bit more since it also turn CAPSLOCK as both ESC and CTRL.

Answer (score 3):

I'm late to answer, but the usual way to swap <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is with the following lines in the `~/.Xmodmap` file:

```
clear Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

This should work with all desktop environments (KDE, Gnome) on most common distros (Ubuntu and Debian family, Fedora and RH family).

Comment: it didn't work on ubuntu 16.04 could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @MaikoID: This is pretty much the canonical way unixy way of swapping CapsLock and Esc. I understand that newer Ubuntu versions with Unity break a lot of "canonical unixy" things, that seems to be why all the other answers here address some version-specific or DE-specific (Unity) method. For what it's worth, this **does** work on Kubuntu, which I personally use.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done from the ["Keyboard Layout" system setting](http://berk.es/2012/06/21/map-capslock-to-escape-in-ubuntu-linux/). Click on "options" for the layout you are using, then under "Caps Lock key behavior" choose "switch Escape and Capslock".

Comment: That's not available in at least 13.10.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the us layout with the default model and variant, you can use this command:
`sudo localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap us "" "" "caps:swapescape"`

Unlike `~/.Xmodmap`, which applies *after* login, this command changes the default system layout and applies to the login screen, which is useful if you use an alternative layout like dvorak.

For more info/examples of the command see this arch wiki article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Using_localectl

Answer (score 0):

On KDE GUI (graphical user interface), This can be done from Keyboard Layout on System Setting. Click on "Input Devices". On the top left corner, click Keyboard. Then click "Advanced" tab.and under "Caps Lock key behavior" choose "switch Escape and Capslock".

Comment: It is great that you have provided an answer to this question. Could you edit your question to expand a little, possibly with the desired outcome once  select "Swap ESC and Caps Lock". is selected.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! In its current state, this answer really isn't complete, and is therefore risking deletion. Please read our [answer] help page, and then come back and [edit] your answer to include more detail, specifically *how* this solves the OP's question. Additionally, please read our [tour] to get a badge and a better idea of how our site works. See you around!

Comment: thanks to your advices. i wish this edit is that you want.

Comment: FYI, the link with your domain doesn't seem to work (at least for me), but the previous IP address domain works.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This does not swap, only maps caps lock to esc. (This was good enough for my vim usecase.)

For ubuntu 16:04 (with i3 environment):
created file ~/.xessionrc with content

```
xmodmap -e "clear lock" #disable caps lock switch
xmodmap -e "keysym Caps_Lock = Escape" #set caps_lock as escape
```

Comment: While this answer may indeed resolve 1/2 the issue that the OP asked about it's showing up in the low quality answer queue due to (I assume) length. You might consider expanding it with further detail. How and why it works perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04:

Create file ~/.xmodmaprc

```
xmodmap -e "clear lock"
xmodmap -e "keycode 9 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock"
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Escape NoSymbol Escape"
```

Source this file to bind the keys in your current session:

```
$ . "$HOME/.xmodmaprc"
```

Append this command to ~/.bashrc for the keys to be bound every time you log in.

This answer is similar to [Gilly's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/670033/947278) but with a lowercase "l" in "clear lock".

Answer (score 0):

I anyone is looking for the KUbuntu equivalent it's under:

System Setting -> Input Devices -> Keyboard -> Advanced Tab -> Caps Lock behavior -> Make Caps Lock an additional Esc

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In Linux Mint 19.3 from the Menu:
Preferences
Keyboard
Layouts
Options
Caps lock behaviour
Swap ESC and Caps Lock

Comment: Unfortunately, Linux Mint is not on-topic for Ask Ubuntu.