# How do I enable Ctrl-Alt-Backspace to kill the X server?

Tags: 13.04, xserver, kill

Unfortunately, there's still a need to kill the XServer from time to time.

Since upgrading to Raring ctrl+alt+backspace is disabled and I can't find this option in the keyboard settings any-more:

- [How can I enable Ctrl+Alt+Backspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace?lq=1)

Is there a way to re-enable it in Raring?

Comment: I think this answer is the closest: http://askubuntu.com/a/81394/235 though we should leave this open in case there's a GUI way, then merge it into that question.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace?lq=1  this solution does not work with the new keyboard setting...

Comment: Yeah, the command line one should still work though.

Comment: yup! 
setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp  thanks!

Comment: Ok I'll fix that one up, and we'll close this one as a dupe, thanks!

Comment: @jorge-castro There are dconf-editor instructions (includes ctrl-alt-backspace) at [swap keys](http://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc/365701#365701) and added to [10622](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10622/how-can-i-enable-ctrlaltbackspace/367995#367995)

Comment: Good work everyone!

Comment: Found the link provided by Jorge. In any case I'll leave an answer here for you to try out.

Answer (score 35):

I only tested this on 13.10+, but you could do the following on the terminal type:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

[image]

This will open the **keyboard configuration** script. Press enter 5 times if you don't want to change any keyboard configuration and only want to kill X. When you get to the Kill X option which looks like this:

[image]

Select **YES** and press enter. Wait a bit while everything configures and after that you should have the ability to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>BCKSPC</kbd> right on the current session. After saving any work you have pending, try it yourself.

Perfect to solve any visual issues or annoying apps.

Comment: Still works in 15.04, it adds `XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"` to /etc/default/keyboard. Reconfiguring this one option leads to an unnecessary `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-30-generic`, but no harm done.

Comment: Confirmed to still work for Ubuntu 16.04