# Keyboard mapping lost using remmina rdp

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, rdp, remmina

I use `setxkbmap -option "caps:swapescape"` to swap caps lock and escape.

When I use the remmina RDP client to connect to a Windows server computer, the keyboard mapping no longer works.

I have tried FreeRDP, same problem there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to permanently switch Caps Lock and Esc](http://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's absolutely normal: if you try to set your local keyboard to let's say Russian and you connect to a Japanese server, you'll still be typing Japanese.  Both servers need to be set to the same keyboard...

That's why at a company I used to work at, we changed the corporate policy that all servers world-wide had to have QWERTY-US-International as their default settings!

Comment: So are you trying to say that RDP dictates that keyboards always send raw scancodes over the wire rather than allowing the client to interpret them and emit virtual scancodes?

Comment: What I'm saying is that I've had tons of problems in the past with keyboard layouts in a multitude of OSes and standardised on US QWERTY Hardware for all machines and haven't had any problems since.  Using `US - International` in SW even allows me to write all Western-European languages, which is all I need.

Comment: @binki  yes, RDP accept only scancodes https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rdpbcgr/7acaec9f-c8a6-4ee9-87d6-d9b89cf56489

Answer (score 1):

[I've just implemented this feature in Remmina](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/merge_requests/2304), therefore any version prior 1.4.21, that as of Today is still not yet released, cannot remap scancodes.

In the meanwhile the only temporary solution is to use xfreerdp if you have at least the version 2.3.0

Comment: Losing my mind that this was working, and now it's not. I didn't have to use the `remmina.keymap` _or_ `rdp_kbd_remap`, it just worked checking `use client keymap` because I already have swapped `ctrl` and `alt` on both. Then it stopped working and I can't figure out why, ha. Now I'm trying both of those previous mentioned options and racking my brain