# Cant swap ESC with CAPS LOCK

Tags: unity, gnome, keyboard, compiz, keyboard-layout

I read a lot o guides on this theme, and this guide worked for me:[How to permanently switch Caps Lock and Esc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc)

However after some recent update it does not work. Additionally i reseted the dconf-editor `org --> gnome --> desktop --> input_scources` `sources` entry as well.

What should i put into the `sources` line? I tried `'(xkb','us'),('xkb','hu')` but even after that ( a language indicator appeared the the notification area) but the `'caps:swapescape'` had no effect.

Where is the problem?

Also when i use `(xkb,en)` the English keyboard layout is not configured correctly. It uses the Hungarian layout like nothing happened.

PS: I also tried the gnome-tweek-tool method, but i think that does the exact same thing and didnt work for me. Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome-flashback compiz

Comment: I have the same problem. Nothing seems to work.