# How can I get Compose bound to Print Screen in graphical applications?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb, compose-key

I was able to get it working in the console, by putting `setxkbmap -options "compose:prsc"` in my bashrc file but it doesn't seem to work in graphical applications.

Any ideas?

(In case you're wondering why I have to use print screen, print screen is where right menu/super should be on my keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setxkbmap) it should be `-option` rather than `-options`!

```
setxkbmap -option "compose:prsc"
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

[I solved it using this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc)

In `dconf-editor -> org -> gnome -> desktop -> input-sources -> xkb-options` I added 'compose:prsc' and it works perfectly.

Comment: Set this as solution of the question please