# Why does my caps lock to escape mapping disappear when I use a USB switch?

Tags: keyboard, capslock

I have been using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc) method to map caps lock to escape in Ubuntu 20.04, and it has worked flawlessly so far.

However, I recently bought a [USB switch](https://www.ugreen.com/products/2-in-4-out-usb-3-0-sharing-switch-box) to switch between controlling two computers with one keyboard and mouse set. And every time I switch the USB output (i.e., from one computer to the other) the caps lock to escape mapping disappears, and I have to remap it.

What will I need to do to make the caps lock to escape mapping stick, even when switching the USB output?

(I tried using Gnome Tweak Tools method too, alas it exhibits the same behavior.)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @david the question now mentions the Ubuntu version (20.04)

Comment: Is this related to this bug? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1899206

Comment: @jeff Yes that definitely seems related. And I suppose I will just have to wait for the update to hit 20.04. Thanks for flagging!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer per se, but like Jeff pointed out, this was indeed part of the bug that was fixed in the latest 20.04 update. After the update the caps lock mapping persisted after switching the USB ports.