# How to permanently remap Caps Lock into Esc key on Ubuntu 22.04.3 with Wayland display server

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, wayland, vim, remapping

My goal is to **PERMANENTLY remap <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> into <kbd>ESC</kbd> key under Ubuntu 22.04.3 with Wayland display server.**

Second requirement is to do it without installing additional software.

I need it for VIM, to be fast and effective using text editor.

I've tried few ways to do it, but since I'm not experienced Linux user, I've failed.
First thing I've tried was in [this article](https://thesynack.com/posts/persistent-capslock-behavior/).
It's written there to execute the following command:
`setxkbmap -option caps:escape`
in order to remap <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> into <kbd>ESC</kbd> and it even works temporarily.

I check the results [here](https://keyboard-test.space/).
But as stated in the article, the mapping is only temporary.

Therefore I'm heading forward to make it PERMANENT, by editing the `/etc/default/keyboard` file. Like so:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="caps:escape"
BACKSPACE="guess"

# https://thesynack.com/posts/persistent-capslock-behavior/
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc
```

But it still won't work after the Ubuntu restart and I don't understand why?

**Is this article I'm using to remap <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> into <kbd>ESC</kbd> X11 specific?**

Because I'm using Wayland display server. It's default in my Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.3.

I've also read carefully this [question over here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc) and all the answers provided. Although there's a lot of knowledge and accepted answers, the whole thread is 10 years old - long before Wayland was the default display server in Ubuntu - therefore I've felt at liberty to ask this question again.

Comment: Have tried the GUI/`gsettings` based answers? They should work on GNOME on Wayland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days of using computer and 4 or 5 power on/off cycles, the <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> started to work as an <kbd>ESC</kbd> key as I initially wanted.

I haven't done anything more than described in the question. And I have no idea, why this `/etc/default/keyboard` file edit, didn't take effect after first computer restart. But I'm happy it finally started working as [described here](https://thesynack.com/posts/persistent-capslock-behavior/).

There's also another file you might want to check, **but not edit.**
It's `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst` file.
You can find all options regarding how the <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> behavior can changed.
This is the short list of the possibilities:

```
  ctrl:nocaps          Caps Lock as Ctrl
  ctrl:swapcaps        Swap Ctrl and Caps Lock
  ctrl:swapcaps_hyper  Caps Lock as Control, Control as Hyper

  caps:swapescape      Swap ESC and Caps Lock
  caps:escape          Make Caps Lock an additional Esc
  caps:escape_shifted_capslock Make unmodified Caps Lock an additional Esc, but Shift + Caps Lock behaves like regular Caps Lock
  caps:super           Make Caps Lock an additional Super
  caps:ctrl_modifier   Caps Lock is also a Ctrl
```

If you want to `grep` the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst` file on your own, try this command:

```
grep "caps" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst
```

**My final `/etc/default/keyboard` file contents, that PERMANENTLY remapped <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> into <kbd>ESC</kbd> key under Ubuntu 22.04.3 is as follows:**

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.


XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="caps:escape"
BACKSPACE="guess"


# https://thesynack.com/posts/persistent-capslock-behavior/
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc
```

But as I've said in the beginning, it only started to work after 2 days and 4 or 5 power on/off cycles - **I don't know why it didn't work from the start.**

Also [this thread was extremely helpful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc) and provided a lot of info regarding how remapping keys under Linux works.

ADDITIONALLY I've found that paragraph [in the same thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc) I've recommended above.

In Debian systems, changes in `/etc/default/keyboard` do not become immediately visible to X. You should either reboot the system, or use `sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change`.
https://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm

In order to activate the changes on the console, run `setupcon`(1).