# Upgraded to 13.10 9 key layout is now upside down 7 8 9 is now 1 2 3

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout

What do I need to revert back to have my 9 key work properly. I do a lot of data entry and cant work like this. There is no way to switch to atm style for the numeric keypad anymore.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Launch or install `gnome-tweak-tools`, go to "typing" and disable "phone numpad style".