# How do you change the default Unicode shortcut CTRL SHIFT U to something else?

Tags: keyboard, unicode

How do you change the default unicode shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to something else?

Comment: It seems that CTRL SHIFT U basically works only in applications that are GTK based. So I guess it must be something inside GTK.

Comment: Does [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#300203), help?

Answer (score -1):

Open *System Settings -> Language Support* and change *Keyboard input method system* to *None*.

Log out and in again.