# Task manager for Ubuntu

Tags: task-management

Is there any task manager for Ubuntu similar to Windows Task Manager?

Comment: I think `System Monitor` is exactly what are you searching for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The default task manager in Ubuntu is called System Monitor. System Monitor is a very good task manager that, compared to Task Manager in Windows, uses much less system resources when it is running. This means that when an application has frozen, you can use the System Monitor to close it without using a lot of system resources which could cause your whole system to freeze.

In case your mouse is frozen too, you can still open the System Monitor from the keyboard if you assign a custom keyboard shortcut to the System Monitor in *System Settings* -> *Keyboard* -> *Shortcuts* tab. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/254442#254442) has screenshots showing how to create a custom keyboard shortcut from the *Keyboard* -> *Shortcuts* tab.

Comment: is there any shortcut to open it..??

Comment: just type system monitor in the dash

Comment: Lock it to Launcher for easy access

Answer (score 13):

You can do a number of things :

1. Search for the System Monitor in the Dash, de facto that's your task manager.
2. Type `top` in the terminal, you'll get a list of processes taking up memory
3. A more interactive and informative version can be obtained by installing `htop`. The command for that is `sudo apt-get install htop`