# Re-mapping Alt Gr Key

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want my <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key to act the same way as the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. I've found a potential solution which is to open up terminal and run the following commands:

```
xmodmap -e "clear mod5"
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_L"
```

This solution works but only temporarily. Whenever I restart the computer it reverts back or even if I'm using my laptop for a few hours the fix is undone.

I'm wondering if their is a permanent solution to this issue.

Just a little about me, I've only started using ubuntu in the last few months so I'm very inexperienced with it so I apologise in advance if I have follow up questions for any potential solutions.

Many thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/300203#300203

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this change permanently for every session, create a file called `.xmodmap` with the the current keymap table, using the following command (after you have run previously `xmodmap -e "clear mod5"` and `xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_L"`):

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.xmodmap
```

Then, create a file called `.xinitrc` in your home directory (using `touch ~/.xinitrc` command), containing the following line/command (use `gedit ~/.xinitrc` command to open the file for editing):

```
xmodmap .xmodmap
```

---

Another solution is to run:

```
sh -c 'xmodmap -e "clear mod5"; xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_L"'
```

command to your startup applications and that'll run it when you log in. Search in Dash for "startup applications".

Comment: Thank you for the answer, just to confirm, where exactly do I save the file?

Comment: @user207489 In your home directory: `/home/your_username`.

Comment: Hi, tried this and it didn't seem to work. Here is exactly what I did so you can see where I'm going wrong. I opened the terminal and ran the two previous commands. I then ran    xmodmap -pke > .xmodmap. I then went to home directory, right clicked and created new document, named it .xinitrc and copied xmodmap .xmodmap into the document and saved it. Restarted and unfortunately it hasn't carried through. Any thoughts? Many thanks for your continued help aswell

Comment: @user207489 Now what is the output of `cat ~/.xmodmap | grep Alt_L` ?

Comment: Output is 
     keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
     keycode 108 = Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L
     keycode 204 = NoSymbol Alt_L NoSymbol Alt_L

Comment: @user207489 It looks ok. And the output of `cat ~/.xinitrc`?

Comment: Returns with: xmodmap .xmodmap
However, still not working following restart I'm afraid.

Comment: So, you made everything good... It should work after restart.

Comment: After reboot problem still persists. Thank you for your help anyway

Comment: @user207489 Another solution is to run `sh -c 'xmodmap -e "clear mod5"; xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_L"'` command to your startup applications and that'll run it when you log in. Search in Dash for startup applications.

Comment: That worked perfect. Thank you so much for your help