# How to reconfigure keyboard (W and P not functioning correctly)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I was reluctant in asking this question but everything I've researched has led me to a dead end. `Shift + w` and `Shift + p` aren't working correctly. So I'm unable to use `W` and `P` unless I use the caps lock.

Right now my keyboard was somehow configured as:

```
    Shift + w == Xterm
    Shift + p == NOTHING
```

but I want my keyboard to be configured like so:

```
    Shift + w == W
    Shift + p == P
    Ctrl + w == Xterm
```

I'm not even sure how to use Xmodmap to accomplish this, or if theres a different way to do this. Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

***Solution***

*The correct solution was to uninstall everything that was associated with `xbindkeys`*

Comment: [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard) maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I eventually came across a file called .xbindkeysrc.scm located at `~/.xbindkeysrc.scm`. So I went through and commented out anything pertaining to `Shift + w` and `Shift + p` and then restarted. Everything is back to normal now.

[image]