# Is there a program to track the keyboard and display it on a terminal?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, bluetooth

I have bought a new Blue Tooth keyboard for my desktop and got it to work with Ubuntu but the problem is that most of the function keys do not work properly and I wonder if the problem is with the keyboard or the driver.

[image]

I thought if there is a tool that show the keyboard code of the keys pressed so I can see if the transmitted codes are the correct ones or not.

Comment: yes it is called `xev`. when key pressed it will show the codes it scanned.

Comment: For function keys (Fn) better to use `acpi_listen`

Comment: Thanks guys, XEV worked for me, it seems like the F5-F12 are not working properly and the DEL key is not working either! I have to contact the seller and return this.

Comment: This Q&A may also be of interest: http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps for that such as: `xev` , [screenkey](https://launchpad.net/screenkey), `showkey` and much others.

Personally i advice you to try [key-mon](http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/)

To download:

first install dependency

```
sudo apt-get install python-xlib
```

download latest version of key-mon from [here](http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/downloads/detail?name=keymon_1.17-1_all.deb&can=2&q=)

now install key-mon

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i keymon_1.17-1_all.deb
```

Now you can run it by command `key-mon`