# Find out the application under the mouse

Tags: window-management

It often happens to me, that an application pops up a question and I wonder to which exact application this window belongs, because if I look in the Launcher there is no application that currently has focus (no white triangle on the right side of the icon when I focus the message window)

Is there a way to find out the belonging of an open window?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Using xdotool**

First make sure `xdotool` is available on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

The following command will print the process name of the window currently in focus:

```
cat "/proc/$(xdotool getwindowpid "$(xdotool getwindowfocus)")/comm"
```

To give yourself more time to focus the window / click on it you can prepend a small sleep duration:

```
sleep 5 && cat "/proc/$(xdotool getwindowpid "$(xdotool getwindowfocus)")/comm"
```

The process name should be displayed after a short amount of time.

---

**Using wininfo**

Wininfo is a graphical utility that displays various information on windows and their properties, including the PID (process ID) associated with the window:

[image: image of PID in wininfo]

`wininfo` should be available in the official repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install wininfo
```

---

Having determined the PID of the window you can then look up the process name associated with it. There are various ways to do this, e.g. by looking at `/proc`:

```
$ cat /proc/17002/comm
gnome-terminal
```

This would be the process name associated with the PID `17002`.

A more elegant way that allows inspecting the process tree context, as suggested by [@Rmano](https://askubuntu.com/users/16395/rmano):

```
$ pstree -a -s -l -p -u 17002
init,1
  └─lightdm,1900
      └─lightdm,3202 --session-child 12 19
          └─lxsession,3307,glutanimate -s LXDE -e LXDE
              └─openbox,3362 --config-file /home/glutanimate/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
                  └─gnome-terminal,17002
                      ├─bash,1841
                      ├─bash,2332
                      ├─bash,2424
                      │   └─pstree,2484 -a -s -l -p -u 17002
                      ├─gnome-pty-helpe,1840
                      ├─{gnome-terminal},1835
                      ├─{gnome-terminal},1836
                      ├─{gnome-terminal},1842
                      └─{gnome-terminal},2269
```

Of course you can also combine `pstree` with the `xdotool` option above (thanks to @rubo77 for pointing this out!):

```
sleep 2; pstree -spaul $(xdotool getwindowpid "$(xdotool getwindowfocus)")
```

---

Sources:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38867/29245

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/how-to-find-the-process-associated-with-a-top-level-x-window-907125/

https://superuser.com/q/632979/170160

Comment: +1 for the nice answer. If the PID is of a child of the main application, you can suggest the use of `pstree -a -s -l -p -u $PID` which is quite nice...

Comment: @Rmano: Oh, that's neat! I added it to the answer.

Comment: The `echo $()` in your commands isn't necessary.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thanks for the pointer. Edited.

Comment: Perfect! didn't know this option of xdotool

Comment: @rubo77 Good thinking! I've added it to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: `xdotool getwindowpid "$(xdotool getwindowfocus)"` → `xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowpid`

Comment: Note that in Ubuntu 17.10 gnome with wayland does not support `xdotool`. Is there a solution for Ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a keyboard-shortcut with this command:

```
zenity --info --text $(xprop $win_id WM_CLASS | cut -d" " -f4-)
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution, +1. However, one smaller issue: if the application doesn't assign a proper WMCLASS (which is oftentimes the case with cryptic dialogs), xprop won't be of any help.

Comment: Did you have an example for an application (popup) that didn't work, thank you.

Comment: I don't have anything specific at hand but I do remember having issues with several Java applications and other obscure programs that didn't have WMCLASS set (or set to something generic like `java-window`). I ran into these kinds of issues a while ago when I was trying to implement application-specific rules in my window manager configuration.

Comment: You are right there is a similar problem with apps created with qml/qt -> https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29396

Comment: How do you create a keyboard-shortcut for this? I tried, as shown below, but zenity doesn't show up

Comment: `bash -c "zenity --info --text $(xprop $win_id WM_CLASS | cut -d' ' -f4-)"` should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xprop` to get the Process ID of the clicked Window:

```
xprop $win_id _NET_WM_PID
```

then analyze it with `pstree`:

```
pstree -spaul $(xprop $win_id _NET_WM_PID | cut -d" " -f3-)
```

This you can redirected to a text-info window with

```
pstree -spaul $(xprop $win_id _NET_WM_PID | cut -d" " -f3-)|zenity --text-info --title "pstree of clicked Window"
```

*I tried to [create a keyboard-shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/a/331632/34298) for this last command (if you need it regularely), but for some reason This doesn't work.*

Answer (score 0):

With xdtool and yad installed you can have a nice GUI App.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do cat "/proc/$(xdotool getwindowpid "$(xdotool 
getwindowfocus)")/comm"; sleep 1; echo -e '\f'; done | yad --no- 
buttons --no-focus --geometry 250x10 --fixed --text-info -- 
title="Active window" --listen
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gnome then can use the following solution.

**Full Disclosure:** The github link bellow is my project.

Please look at https://github.com/blueray453/gnome-utils-by-blueray453/blob/main/appFunctions.js

```
GetAppFromFocusedWindow() {
    let w = global.get_window_actors().find(w => w.meta_window.has_focus() == true);

    let tracker = Shell.WindowTracker.get_default();
    let app = tracker.get_window_app(w.meta_window);
    return app.get_id();
}
```

You need gnome extension to access data about windows and shell. You see the `global.` and `Shell.WindowTracker`, you can not import these is gjs or python.

Please check [Could not find Meta, Shell & St in Python's GTK bindings which gnome extension documentaion has](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76676215/1772898).

If you install this extension then the command you would run is:

```
dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/GnomeUtilsApps org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.GnomeUtilsApps.GetAppFromFocusedWindow
```

You can bind this command to a key.