# Weird on screen keyboard appearing when pressing ctrl+alt+b

Tags: shortcut-keys, onscreen-keyboard

Whenever the focus is on a text edit element, the key combination ctrl+alt+b brings up a weird on screen keyboard:

[image: screenshot]

I wanted to remove this binding (or delete the program), but I can find neither! As you can see in the image, the OSK is not Florence nor Onboard, nor any I could find online. A reverse google image throws no results.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, with openbox as window manager, and no DE.

Comment: Can you find out the application's command by following the question here: http://askubuntu.com/q/508527/367990 ?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that, but the problem is that xdotool is reporting the name of the application where I've pressed ctrl+alt+b, I can't get the name of the little dialog with the OSD. grepping ps for "osd","key", or "virtual" doesn't yield any unnormal process.

Comment: Well - might it be that the on-screen keyboard is a part of your editor application then? Does it happen on other programs as well? Or only there? Which one is it?

Comment: It happens on every program, as I said "whenever the focus is on a text edit element"

Comment: Also, when I click "Latin" it switches to other layouts: latin, fullwidth, hirakana, greek, russian, symbol table, etc. Maybe this has something to do with openbox? It seems more like low level.

Comment: That could be, but I have no idea... I stayed with Unity or XFCE, never had openbox.

Comment: What really gets me is that there's absolutely no mention of this OSK anywhere. My paranoid self fears some sort of wierd inverse keylogger, where instead of logging my keys someone's trying to get me to use the OSK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Probably it's caused by **fctix**, which is some software, which supports input methods. For some reason, I couldn't successfully kill this process from terminal. I found it in graphical system monitor and killed the process from GUI. After that, while typing Ctrl+alt+B, weird keyboard wasn't displayed anymore. You can also try to remove this software.

Instruction showing how to remove fctix can be found here:
http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/precise/universe/f/fcitx/uninstall/index.html

Uninstalling:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove fcitx
```

Purging config data:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove fcitx
```

Comment: Perfect, this did the trick!

Comment: If you need fcitx like me, you can just disable the Virtual Key Board addon via Fcitx Configuration.

Answer (score 5):

The way to solve the issue but keep `fcitx`:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/fcitx/addon/fcitx-vk.conf
```

add to the file

```
Enable=false
```

logout, login again

Comment: Worked, only the key was named `Enabled`, not `Enable` (Ubuntu 18.10).

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem. I tried [piotr.wittchen's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/724811/527764) and it did work, but I couldn't input Chinese any more after that.

So, I reinstalled fcitx, and modified its **Global Config** in **Input Method Configuration**. Choose **Show Advanced Options**, and make **Switching Virtual Keyboard** empty. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this by below steps:
Settings->Fcitx config->Global config->Show advanced Options(Left bottom) -> Switching Virtual Keyboard -> Pressing Esc.