# Create custom keyboard shortcut to send Super+2

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm trying to set my numpad to be a media control centre. I want to have the 0 key pull up Clementine and bring it to the foreground. Right now I have it set to *launch* Clementine, but it just dances in the launcher and doesn't come to the foreground. So, I have Clementine pinned to the second slot on the launcher, and I want to set up a custom key shortcut via the Keyboard Settings. The question is, how do I send Super+2 as a command?

Second, I want the plus and minus keys to send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> (for browser navigation).

Third, and less important, I want the period key to open Clementine's EQ, and 7 and 9 to send Fast Forward and Rewind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I send Super+2 as a command

You could use `xdotool` for this (`sudo apt-get install xdotool` to install):

```
xdotool key super+2
```

---

> Second, I want the plus and minus keys to send Alt+Left and Alt+Right

This should work:

```
xdotool key alt+Right
xdotool key alt+Left
```

---

> 7 and 9 to send Fast Forward and Rewind

You could give these a try:

```
xdotool key XF86AudioNext
xdotool key XF86AudioPrev
```

---

> I want the period key to open Clementine's EQ

This is where things get tricky. Without a dedicated shortcut you would have to program an `xdotool` macro to access the menu and launch the equalizer, but I am not quite sure if that would work, either.

---

In any case, as you can see most of these customizations can be performed using virtual `xdotool` key presses.

If you are wondering how to assign these commands to hotkeys of your choice make sure to check out this Q&A:

[How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. The Super+2 command works great, although some of the time it behaves like just Super. Hmm... In any case, it's something.

The browser nav commands work perfectly. I found out Clementine actually has command line controls for nearly everything, so for fast forward and rewind, I use 

    `clementine --seek-by 2` and 
    `clementine --seek-by -2`.

Still working on the EQ part of it.

Answer (score 3):

Another (I think easier) approach would be to use [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey).

Once the keys are set as hotkeys, you can use custom defined phrases to have them emit almost anything you want.

---

AutoKey also supports scriptis written in Python that can do almost anything when they are activated by a trigger phrase or hotkey. You can even tell a script to only work in certain windows so the hotkeys/trigger phrases behave as normal keys elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can grab the scancodes of the keys and assign the shortcuts manually. The article below lists some utilities that might help:
http://tuxdiary.com/2014/03/07/get-scancode-for-keys-on-ubuntu/