# Alt-shift: skip some of the languages?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I use alt-shift to switch between keyboard layouts in Ubuntu 14.04. I have 3 languages enabled, but I use one of them much less often.

How could I make alt-shift skip the rarely used language(s)?

Comment: I need the same! KDE (plasma 5 I think, I couldn't find a reference) has a feature that allows one to control which languages you change with the keyboard shortcut and which just by the mouse. It would be awesome to see such a feature in Unity one day!

Comment: I solved my need for multiple languages using the "compose key" at the end. So, I still have two layouts (en-US and el-GR), which are very different, but I can also write latin-based languages with the en-US and use the compose key to insert accent marks, or special symbols. E.g. in German, "compose+u+:" gives ü, "compose+s+s" gives ß, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could I make alt-shift skip the rarely used language(s)?

I would assume you can not. The system does not count keyboard lay-outs used to determine how often it is used.

Then again it becomes possible if you change the question to ....

> How could I skip the rarely used language(s)?

Then the answer would be: by using another key combination and change that key combination to switch between the 2 lay-outs you do want to switch between.

Lay-outs are numbered from 0. So the 1st and 2nd lay-out are activated with respectively...

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1
```

(or "2" if you, in your case, need the 3rd keyboard).

This will take up 2 keys though: you can add one to a key like control + P and the other to control + O. If you want this to be one key you would need to change the 0 in

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0
```

to a variable that toggles the 0 to a 1 and a 1 to a 0.

---

That would be this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current $(($(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources | grep -Po "'[[:alpha:]]+'\)" | wc -l)-1))
```

This would allow you to use 1 key and make it a toggle.

---

Refer to [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard) on how to set this. Tweak tools and compiz action plugin would be 2 methods on setting those.

Comment: thanks. 1. I'm not asking for the system to do statistics, I am asking about a way to manually tell which languages should be included in the switch behaviour.  2. Are you suggesting ctrl+O and ctrl+P because there is an inherent problem with capturing alt+shift?

Comment: 1. as a stated: I do not believe you can from the current methods, you need to create your own method (example included in the answer). 2. No, those 2 bindings are just examples if a toggle does not work (that last command I found on the web). alt+shift is set in keyboard controls as the default switching of all installed keyboards. keeping the defaults and creating your own binding (to me ;) ) seems smarter than altering defaults.

Answer (score 1):

This is what "switch to previous layout" should do but it does not on Ubuntu. It just doesn't work.

[image]

It does work great in OSX. It loops through the layouts you 've used lately(usually two).