# Logitech K750: dead_circumflex and less interchanged

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, logitech, logitech-unifying

I'm using the german Macintosh version fo the Logitec K750 and everything works fine but unfortunatly the <kbd><</kbd> and the <kbd>^</kbd> keys are interchanged.

I tried to use the keyTouch-Editor to fix this and build a new file for my keyboard but is was unable to activate this. Furthermore I only found the Editor but not `keytouch` itself in the Software Center neither via `apt-get` …

How can I change the two keys to a normal behaviour and btw. is it possible to make the left <kbd>alt</kbd> key behave like the right one?

---

Update: I tried the answers from [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/254424/54477) but without succes. I hope someone can guide me on how to

1. **swap <kbd><</kbd> and  <kbd>^</kbd> keys**
2. **make left <kbd>alt</kbd> behave the same as right <kbd>alt</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

I found a **partial** answer myself: To change <kbd><</kbd> and  <kbd>^</kbd> I added the following lines to the file `~/.Xmodmap`

```
keycode 49 = less greater bar
keycode 94 = dead_circumflex degree notsign
```

Unfortunately these changes **get lost** after a reboot/logout and I have to call `xmodpad ~/.Xmodmap` again. How can I make this automatically happen?

Comment: You can use that command as a startup script in `~/.profile` I think maybe

Comment: Thanks … I would try but I’m not using Ubuntu at the moment …