# Ubuntu equivalent of Karbiner for Mac?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm looking for a relatively easy way for doing custom keyboard shortcuts on Ubuntu. Coming from OS X, there was an amazing tool called Karabiner that allowed me to easily remap keys to predefined shortcuts, and even add custom ones. I was wondering if there is a similar tool for Ubuntu.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard

Answer (score 3):

## keyboardlayouteditor

A keyboard layout editor for Linux.

Its designed to be user friendly and easy to use. If you can get this installed, you might just have a blast.

[Website](http://code.google.com/p/keyboardlayouteditor/)

## xmodmap

The xmodmap program

Is used to edit and display the keyboard modifier map and keymap table that are used by client applications to convert event keycodes into keysyms. It is a part of the X.Org project.

[Website](http://www.x.org/)