# How can I make Alt+LeftClick work the same as a right click?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there a way to make <kbd>Alt</kbd>+LeftClick (holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking the left mouse button) work the same as a right click so that I don't need the right mouse button?

Can a click be part of a shortcut in keyboard settings?

Answer (score 2):

There is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> which is the same like a simple Rightclick.

So you can do a binding on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left mouse</kbd> for this combination.

How you can do such binding can be found in this nice topic:
[How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/254424/448613)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I hav been unable to get ay f those to work. I can see how to make a keyboard shortcut or a mouse button shortcut, but I do not see how to make a key plus muse button shortcut.