# Sequential key bindings

Tags: shortcut-keys, latex

I was wondering whether it's possible to define sequential keybindings in any sensible way. What I want is that pressing

```
Esc + l + Esc
```

produces for example the text

```
\lambda
```

So basically get Mathematica-style key input in my LaTeX editor.

It should not be a permanent change but rather I want to turn it on and off when I want. For instance by changing the keyboard layout...

Any ideas?

Comment: Will anything here help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard ?