# Change currency key symbol

Tags: keyboard

15.04 Vivid.

I am using a standard US keyboard with US English in Europe. How can I PERMANENTLY change the keyboard map so that when I press the " <kbd>$</kbd> " (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>) I get a Euro currency symbol?

Comment: And which key you want to use for `$`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try and see if one of the keyboard layouts in the "text entry" tab of the Settings suits you.
If not, you can manually change the behaviour of one key. To do so there are specific programmes.
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard) related question has lots of answers on how to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. If you keyboard is set to Europe, the Euro symbol should be on you 'E' key.

Comment: Of course you can. You can do lots of things. Also, his keyboard is NOT set to Europe, but to US english.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that he said IN Europe, instead of SET to Europe. My bad.