# How to enable ALT Gr key as ALT R for Emacs on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, emacs

Emacs is famous for [causing tendinitis](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_pinky.html), but one must remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> come in pairs, at left and right of the keyboard :-)

However, in Ubuntu 16.04, <kbd>Alt R</kbd> behavior is <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, messing with Emacs shortcuts. Thus usually I type <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for the sake of my fist.

Thus, how could we:

1. Configure `~/.emacs.d/init.el` to understand <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> as <kbd>Alt R</kbd> (or)
2. Change the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> behavior for all applications

It is not about creating a [shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard), its about change the key mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add English US (or any other layout without ALTGr) to your Text Entry settings.

Then, use the standard Super + Space to use Emacs with US keybindings. Unfortunately, you won't be able to use any local characters specific to your country.

[image]

Unfortunately, you can't just reconfigure ALTGr to ALT through emacs init. Altering your xkb map would be a solution but you didn't want that. This solution is more GUI-oriented. Enjoy.

Comment: I used to change ALT Gr behavior configuring `.xmodmap`, but it is not working at Ubuntu 20.04.