# Ubuntu+1: How to map ALT Gr key as ALT R on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 20.04

## TL; DR

How do I re-map <kbd>ALT R</kbd> to work as <kbd>ALT R</kbd> instead of <kbd>ALT Gr</kbd> on Ubuntu 20.04?

## Details

As described in [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424), I've executed `xev` at Ubuntu 20.04 in order to discover <kbd>ALT L</kbd> and <kbd>ALT R</kbd> keycodes:

- <kbd>ALT L</kbd> `keycode  64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L)`
- <kbd>ALT R</kbd> `keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift)`

Running `xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap`, the following configuration was saved:

```
keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
```

while `gsettings` provides:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['lv3:menu_switch']
```

**Theoretically** re-mapping `108` at `~/.Xmodmap` should be enough:

```
keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R
```

However, even running `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` and also saving this command at `~/.xinitrc`, **the modifications did not take effect** immediately or after login again at Ubuntu.

Thus it is not possible to [execute extensible commands in Emacs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813332) using <kbd>ALT R</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> at Emacs

So what is the proper way of changing <kbd>ALT R</kbd> behavior?

## References:

- [Ask Ubuntu: How can I change what keys on my keyboard do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424)
- [Ask Ubuntu: How to enable ALT Gr key as ALT R for Emacs on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813332)

Comment: Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be reported on Launchpad https://askubuntu.com/a/5126/197910 so that developers can see, track and fix these issues.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/x11-xserver-utils/+bug/1872501

Comment: Look at [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1867548).

Comment: @K7AAY I just made a clean install of 19.10 on VirtualBox and the modifications in `.Xmodmap` took effect as expected.

Comment: @JPVentura: Why would you need to make modifications on 19.10? Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The modifications worked in 19.10 but not in 20.04. I am using English INTL with dead-keys at Microsoft Natural 4000 Wired. Considering I write in PT-BR, EN and use Emacs, this is the best layout.

Comment: @JPVentura: I see, and I suspect that it's explained by the bug I linked to. With that said, and considering that you disable the access to 3:rd and 4:th level symbols anyway, why don't you simply use the basic _English (US)_ keyboard layout instead of messing with `~/.Xmodmap`?

Comment: Because I still would not be able to write _opção fácil_ em Brazilian Portuguese ;-). This layout works perfectly on OS X.

Comment: @JPVentura: Fair enough. Can you please edit your question and show us the output of the terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem trying to remap my Control_L key on Ubuntu20.04 and gnome-control-center 3.36.2. According to @Gunnar's bug link, a fix has been provided in 3.36.1 already... Any ideas?