# Shortcut to open new browser

Tags: keyboard, firefox, shortcut-keys, browser

I configured "open browser" to ctrl-alt-w here, since my keyboard does not have a "www" key:

**System Settings** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts**

Unfortunately firefox opens in a new window. That's not what I want. I want to open a new tab.

Is the current default really the best default for the 21 century? AFAIK most people use browser tabs, and not several browser windows.

Comment: I'm confused... once you've opened your browser, can't you just open a new tab with ctrl+t?

Comment: @Zanna: I want to hit ctrl-alt-w and the browser should get the focus with a new tab beside my other tabs. Of course ctrl+t works. But I want a shortcut that works everywhere, not just with the browser having the focus. Example: a terminal has the focus, and I want a new browser tab. Got it? Please ask, if not.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign this command below to a custom shortcut, it will always try to open a new tab in an already open Firefox window, if possible:

```
firefox -new-tab about:newtab
```

See [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/q/254424/367990) (especially [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/254442/367990) for a GUI method) if you don't know how to set custom shortcuts.