# Custom shortcut to open new browser tab and get focused in address bar

Tags: shortcut-keys, firefox, google-chrome, default-browser

Here is a lot of advices that describe how to open a new tab in certain browser using custom shortcuts.
But all the ways I found here like [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831135/shortcut-to-open-new-browser) doesn't help to be focused in the browsers address bar after switching to just opened tab. The goal is - simple press shortcut and continue to enter my query.
Second, it will be perfect to got some universal command rather a command for certain browser. It will help when default browser setting will be changed.
Thanks.

Comment: ctrl+t in firefox should do the trick, I always end up in the adressbar when doing this.

Comment: @Videonauth I mean global shortcut key in OS settings, which I can use everywhere to switch to the browser, open new tab and put cursor in address bar.