# How to restore app switcher hotkey Alt Tab in xfce4?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried another app switcher (Skippy-XD). In order for that to work, I reassigned Alt + Tab to launch Skippy-XD instead of the default xfce4 app switcher. I did not like skippy-xd however, so I uninstalled it. Now Alt Tab doesn't do anything. Restoring the default hotkeys in the Settings Manager does not solve the problem.

How do I bind Alt Tab to launch the xfce4 app switcher again?

Answer (score 4):

Easier method: Settings Manager > Window Manager > Keyboard tab. Change the "Cycle Windows" shortcut to Alt-Tab by either double-clicking on the entry or pressing the "Edit" key. When you do either, you will be prompted with a dialog box to press the keyboard combination - press "Alt+Tab".

Comment: this is the proper Xfce answer

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Open ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml

Look for the lines that have to do with Alt Tab, there should be two, make sure the first one looks like this:

```
<property name="<Alt>Tab" type="empty">
```

And the second one like this:

```
<property name="<Alt>Tab" type="string" value="cycle_windows_key"/>
```

Save the file and log off and back in.

Answer (score 0):

Try xbindkeys.
You can read more about it in a question here:

[How can I change what keys on my keyboard do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/254425#254425)

This worked for me to override a key binding that I didn't like on ubuntu.
There are also many more options for key-binding modification in that post, so consider those solutions as well.

Comment: That allows me to bind commands to keys, but what is the command that launches the app switcher? I've been trying to find out, without success so far.