# Alt-Tab and Workspace Switcher shortcuts aren't working on Xubuntu 21.10

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce, application-switcher

I have switched from Ubuntu Desktop to Xubuntu desktop because Ubuntu no longer supports desktop icons. Unfortunately, in the move I seem to have lost the ability to cycle windows with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and the ability to change workspaces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> + cursor keys.

I've tried:

- checking the contents of `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`: it has the expected (and confusing) contents that seem to work for everyone else
- changing the key definition in Settings → Window Manager → Keyboard. Even deleting them, logging out, logging back in, redefining them makes no difference.
- checking that the keys on my preferred keyboard are generating the right scan codes using xev.

There may be some conflicting setting hanging about from the regular Ubuntu installation, but I can't locate where they might be.  I have tried the answers in [How to restore app switcher hotkey Alt Tab in xfce4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841965/how-to-restore-app-switcher-hotkey-alt-tab-in-xfce4) to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this, but not in a way that identified the cause.

Because this is a system that's been upgraded through many versions of Ubuntu Desktop (possibly starting with 16.04), and now migrated over to Xubuntu Desktop 21.10, my `~/.config` folder was full of extraneous and perhaps contradictory junk.

Here's how I resolved the issue:

1. moved the contents of `~/.config` to a new `~/Desktop/dotconfig` folder
2. logged out
3. logged back in. At this point, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> started to work again, confirming that there were conflicting configuration settings before
4. Carefully restored files/folders from `~/Desktop/dotconfig` back to `~/.config` that I knew I'd have a use for. Any new files or folders in `~/.config` that Xubuntu had recently created I didn't overwrite.

There are a few settings that I still need to restore - I've lost my beloved <kbd>Compose</kbd> key bindings, for one - but the system behaves much more like I'd expect now.

Comment: ... and now there's seemingly no way that <kbd>Compose</kbd> will work. All the tools I have available say the correct key is defined, yet it does nothing

Answer (score 1):

For me (and many other people) Alt-Tab somehow gets disabled when using Thunderbird and Wayland together, seemingly after one sends a first message with Thunderbird. It's probably something about the "sending message" window not getting terminated correctly. Anyway, see [bug 1932328](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1932328), but the [comment 18 fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thunderbird/+bug/1932328/comments/18), putting Thunderbird into XWayland mode, which worked for me, seems to be a fix for many other users.

Another workaround can be to go to keyboard shortcuts and swap Alt-tab and Alt-esc. The latter is "direct window switching" and is similar but different to alt-tab switching. More visually distracting but same functionality.

Comment: I'm not running Wayland, but this answer might help someone else

Comment: Comment 18 also fixed the problem for me on Ubuntu 21.10