# How to bind all functions of 'Shift' button to another one?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 16.10, xbindkeys, xte

I have a keyboard with broken <kbd>Shift</kbd> button, but I have some additional buttons like <kbd>Mail</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> etc.

I want to make my <kbd>Mail</kbd> button as <kbd>Shift</kbd> button (because I have used Windows and software for my keyboard wich makes it).

I have almost read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/254425/538376), but it isn't enough. As I understand, I need to write in `.xbindkeysrc` something like

```
"xte 'keydown Shift'"
"xte 'keydown XF86Mail'"

"xte 'keyup Shift'"
"xte 'keyup XF86Mail'"
```

and it didn't work. But the code below works in that way: after press and release <kbd>Mail</kbd> button both <kbd>Shift</kbd> buttons still be pressed (as I have checked using a virtual keyboard).

```
"xte 'keydown Shift_L'"
XF86Mail
```

How can I use one of the additional buttons as <kbd>Shift</kbd>?