# Change close Window shortcut to Alt+Audio Previous

Tags: 16.04, unity, shortcut-keys, window

On my laptop, I'm currently using the keys from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> as multimedia keys (e.g. volume up, volume down, play/pause, prev, etc).

The problem is that the standard shortcut for closing a window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>) is not working, in fact I need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

In order to avoid pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> and having the standard behavior without disabling multimedia keys I would like to map <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Audio Previous</kbd> (which is the multimedia key on <kbd>F4</kbd> on my keyboard) as closing shortcut.

Setting this in System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts is recognized properly by the interface but it's not actually working.

Same thing if I change using Dconf Editor, again, I can change the value (and apparently it's saved correctly) but the shortcut does not work.

How is it really possible to change such setting?

Alternatively is it possible to map <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Audio Previous</kbd> to actually send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to the window manager?

Using Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity.

Comment: Have you tried changing it in the BIOS settings?

Comment: @oltreseba have you tryed `Ctrl+W`?
if that doesnt satisfy you there are several good articles about xbindkeys which allows for more accurate binding of keys [AskUbuntu Article](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

Comment: Chai T. Rex: of course I can disable this setting in the bios setting, but then I have to press fn every time I want to use a multimedia key, and that's not what i want. @WooJoo i'll give xbindkeys a try.

Comment: You can use Ctrl+Q to close most apps

Comment: Ctrl + Q is not the right solution at all, for two reason:
1 - as you noticed not all apps follow this shortcut (e.g. google chrome does not), therefore it's un-predicatable;
2 - Ctrl + Q is actually an "in application" shortcut that does not only close the window (like alt + f4 does) but actually exit the application. This cause applications that should not really close, and that usually go to the systray  to actually close.