# Best software for taking screen shots in ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, screenshot

What is the best software to take perfect screen shots in ubuntu 14
The **best** means :

> 1.It should take quick screen shots.
>   2.It should not interfare with other files running during that instance.
>   3.The quality of screen shots should be nice.

Comment: Try screenshot.

Comment: i want to know other interactive softwares .I don't know how my printscreen key'and other keys' is not working.

Comment: "Best software" is a broad and opinion-based question. Best software for one person might not be best for the other.

Comment: Can you give any one out there ?its commnd to install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shutter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=shutter) is really great. Allows easy screenshot taking with various options (Current window, under mouse cursor, full screen and more). Has nice editing options, including crop.

See also the Shutter homepage for more information : [Shutter homepage](http://shutter-project.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [adding a keyboard shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard) that runs the command `scrot`. This is good for basic functionality which mirrors that of the print screen key.